# How can I map True/False to 1/0 in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, boolean

I have a column in python `pandas` DataFrame that has boolean `True`/`False` values, but for further calculations I need `1`/`0` representation. Is there a quick `pandas`/`numpy` way to do that?

Comment: What further calculations are required?

Comment: To parrot @JonClements, why do you need to convert bool to int to use in calculation? bool works with arithmetic directly (since it is internally an int).

Comment: @cs95 - Pandas uses numpy bools internally, and they can behave a little differently. In plain Python, True + True = 2, but in Pandas, numpy.bool_(True) + numpy.bool_(True) = True, which may not be the desired behavior on your particular calculation.

Comment: I needed it because statsmodels would not allow boolean data for logistic regression.

Answer (score 553, accepted):

A succinct way to convert a single column of boolean values to a column of integers 1 or 0:

```py
df["somecolumn"] = df["somecolumn"].astype(int)
```

Comment: The corner case is if there are NaN values in `somecolumn`. Using `astype(int)` will then fail. Another approach, which converts `True` to 1.0 and `False` to 0.0 (floats) while preserving NaN-values is to do: `df.somecolumn = df.somecolumn.replace({True: 1, False: 0})`

Comment: @DustByte Good catch!

Comment: @DustByte Couldn't you just use `astype(float)` and get the same result?

Comment: if the value is text and a lowercase "true" or "false" then first do a astype(bool].astype(int) and the conversion will work.   Sas outputs is bools as lowercase true and false.

Comment: how can this be applied to a number of columns?

Comment: Thank you. Should I do this to all columns or there is a command without specifying column name?

Comment: You can also consider nullable integer types instead of `int`, like `"Int64"` or `"Int8"` (note the uppercase)

Answer (score 96):

Just multiply your Dataframe by 1 (int)

```
[1]: data = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, True], [False, False, True]])
[2]: print data
          0      1     2
     0   True  False  True
     1   False False  True

[3]: print data*1
         0  1  2
     0   1  0  1
     1   0  0  1
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this solution?

Comment: @AMC There are none, it's a hacky way to do it.

Comment: @AMC if your dataframe has `float` types beside booleans this method won't ruin them, `df.astype(int)` does. And since it's hacky it's probably a good idea to make intention clear with comment like `# bool -> int`.

Comment: There is an advantage of using `data * 1` against `data + 0` with mixed types – it works on strings as well, where `data + 0` throws an error. Equivalent performance-wise.

Comment: advantage: slightly shorter

Answer (score 56):

This question specifically mentions a single column, so the currently accepted answer works. However, it doesn't generalize to multiple columns. For those interested in a general solution, use the following:

```
df.replace({False: 0, True: 1}, inplace=True)
```

This works for a DataFrame that contains columns of many different types, regardless of how many are boolean.

Answer (score 49):

`True` is `1` in Python, and likewise `False` is `0`<sup>*</sup>:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

You should be able to perform any operations you want on them by just treating them as though they were numbers, as they *are* numbers:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> True * 5
5
```

So to answer your question, no work necessary - you already have what you are looking for.

<sup>* Note I use *is* as an English word, not the Python keyword `is` - `True` will not be the same object as any random `1`.</sup>

Comment: Just be careful with data types if doing floating point math: `np.sin(True).dtype` is float16 for me.

Comment: I've got a dataframe with a boolean column, and I can call `df.my_column.mean()` just fine (as you imply), but when I try: `df.groupby("some_other_column").agg({"my_column":"mean"})` I get `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, so it appears they are **NOT** always the same. Just FYI.

Comment: In pandas version 24 (and maybe earlier) you can aggregate `bool` columns just fine.

Comment: It looks like numpy also throws errors with boolean types: `TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.`  Using @User's answer fixes this.

Comment: Another reason it's not the same: df.col1 + df.col2 + df.col3 doesn't work for `bool` columns as it does for `int` columns

Answer (score 23):

You also can do this directly on Frames

```
In [104]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = True, B = False),index=range(3))

In [105]: df
Out[105]: 
      A      B
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False

In [106]: df.dtypes
Out[106]: 
A    bool
B    bool
dtype: object

In [107]: df.astype(int)
Out[107]: 
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  1  0

In [108]: df.astype(int).dtypes
Out[108]: 
A    int64
B    int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) for convert boolean to integers:

```py
df["somecolumn"] = df["somecolumn"].view('i1')
```

Answer (score 3):

If the column is of the type object, and for example you want to convert it to integer:

`df["somecolumn"] = df["somecolumn"].astype(bool).astype(int)`

Comment: Make sure to put code in code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transformation for your data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data condition)
```

## transforming True/False in 1/0

```
df = df*1
```

Comment: This is identical to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647160/11301900), posted 3 years earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I had to map FAKE/REAL to 0/1 but couldn't find proper answer.

Please find below how to map column name 'type' which has values FAKE/REAL to 0/1 
(Note: similar can be applied to any column name and values)

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 'FAKE', 'type'] = 0
df.loc[df['type'] == 'REAL', 'type'] = 1
```

Comment: Much simpler: `df['type'] = df['type'].map({'REAL': 1, 'FAKE': 0})`. In any case, I'm not sure it's too relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for providing simpler solution. As I mentioned in answer, I was trying to find solution for slightly different question, and only similar questions like this were available. Hope my answer and your solution will help someone in future.

Comment: There are other questions which already cover that, though, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/20250771.

Answer (score 2):

Tried and tested:

`df[col] = df[col].map({'True': 1,'False' :0 })`

If there are more than one columns with True/False, use the following.

```
for col in bool_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].map({'True': 1,'False' :0 })
```

@AMC wrote this in a comment

Answer (score 0):

This is a reproducible example based on some of the existing answers:

```py
import pandas as pd


def bool_to_int(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    """Convert the boolean to binary representation, maintain NaN values."""
    return s.replace({True: 1, False: 0})


# generate a random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10), "b": range(10, 0, -1)}).assign(
    a_bool=lambda df: df["a"] > 5,
    b_bool=lambda df: df["b"] % 2 == 0,
)

# select all bool columns (or specify which cols to use)
bool_cols = [c for c, d in df.dtypes.items() if d == "bool"]

# apply the new coding to a new dataframe (or can replace the existing one)
df_new = df.assign(**{c: lambda df: df[c].pipe(bool_to_int) for c in bool_cols})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to convert True/False values to 1/0 in a Pandas DataFrame is to use the **pd.Series.view()** method. This method creates a new NumPy array that shares the memory with the original DataFrame column, but with a different data type. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample DataFrame with True/False values
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True], 'B': [False, True, False]})

# convert True/False values to 1/0 using view()
df['A'] = df['A'].view('i1')
df['B'] = df['B'].view('i1')

# print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score -1):

True % (an odd number) = 1
False % (an odd number) = 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).