# Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying do something that should be really simple in pandas, but it seems anything but. I'm trying to add a column to an existing pandas dataframe that is a mapped value based on another (existing) column. Here is a small test case:

```
import pandas as pd
equiv = {7001:1, 8001:2, 9001:3}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001]} )
df["B"] = equiv(df["A"])
print(df)
```

I was hoping the following would result:

```
      A   B
0  7001   1
1  8001   2
2  9001   3
```

Instead, I get an error telling me that equiv is not a callable function. Fair enough, it's a dictionary, but even if I wrap it in a function I still get frustration. So I tried to use a map function that seems to work with other operations, but it also is defeated by use of a dictionary:

```
df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x:equiv[x])
```

In this case I just get KeyError: 8001. I've read through documentation and previous posts, but have yet to come across anything that suggests how to mix dictionaries with pandas dataframes. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 145):

The right way of doing it will be `df["B"] = df["A"].map(equiv)`.

```
In [55]:

import pandas as pd
equiv = {7001:1, 8001:2, 9001:3}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001]} )
df["B"] = df["A"].map(equiv)
print(df)
      A  B
0  7001  1
1  8001  2
2  9001  3

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

And it will handle the situation when the key does not exist very nicely, considering the following example:

```
In [56]:

import pandas as pd
equiv = {7001:1, 8001:2, 9001:3}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001, 10000]} )
df["B"] = df["A"].map(equiv)
print(df)
       A   B
0   7001   1
1   8001   2
2   9001   3
3  10000 NaN

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if your data is string instead of int? This just gives me NaNs for strings.

Comment: Nevermind, see answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict

Comment: And what if your `equiv` dict has lists instead of integers? How can you map only the n-th element of that list?

Comment: I always get this warning with this method. What is the solution????            SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.