# Creating a new Pandas column based on a dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this :

```
{'Andrew':['Photography'],'Peter':['Travel']}
```

I also have a db that looks like this:

```
ID      Hobby
1       Travel
2       Photography
3       Football
..........
```

I would like to add a thirth column to the Dataframe to achieve:

```
ID     Hobby        Name
1      Travel       Peter
2      Photography  Andrew
3      Football     NaN
```

I did find this [Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary), but I do not need the column to contain the value from the dictionary, but the key. 
Thanks

Comment: So what's stopping you from constructing a new dict with the keys and values reversed? After which the linked question would work for you?

Comment: I do feel silly now. That did work

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
equiv = {'Andrew':['Photography'],'Peter':['Travel'], 'Jack': ['Football']}

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Hobby':[equiv[x][0] for x in equiv], 'Name': [key for key in equiv.keys()]})
print(df)
```