# Create a new column based on other columns and a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

let's suppose I have a dataframe with at least two columns col1 and col2. Also I have a dictionary of dictionaries, whose keys consist of the values in col1 resp. col2.

```
import pandas as pd
dict_of_dicts = {'x0': {'y0':1, 'y1':2, 'y2':3}, 'x1': {'y0':0, 'y1':0,    'y2':1}, 'x2': {'y0':2, 'y1':1, 'y2':3}} 
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x2'], 'col2': ['y0', 'y1', 'y0']} )
print(df)
  col1 col2
0   x1   y0
1   x2   y1
2   x2   y0
```

Now I want to create a third column that contains the value of my dictionary with the keys given by col1 and col2 in the respective line. Something like

```
df['col3'] = dict_of_dicts[df['col1']][df['col2']].
```

The result should look like this:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0   x1   y0     0
1   x2   y1     1
2   x2   y0     2
```

It should be similar to "map", as explained here [Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary)

But I rely on two columns. Could anybody help me with that, please?

By the way: I actually **don't have to** use a dictionary of dictionaries (as just described). I could also use a table (dataframe) with the one set of keys as index set of the dataframe and the other set of keys as the column names. But also here I don't know how to access a specific "cell" which would be specified by the values in col1 and col2.

I hope my problem is clear.

Thank you, Nadja

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match what inspection suggests you're looking for.  Is that 0 correct?

Comment: you are right, there was a mistake I just corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Hello everybody,

I have kind of a follow-up question: Say I do not have a dict of dicts but a dataframe. And instead of having the keys for the dict of dicts, I have the index and the column name of the data frame.
How would it work then?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have a follow-up question which is different, then open a new question with your new input, desired output, what you tried, and why it didn't work.  StackOverflow works in a question/answer format, not threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simple [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with anonimous function should work fine:

```
df.apply(lambda x: dict_of_dicts[x.col1][x.col2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Great, fast answer that works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your desired output is correct? x1 - y0 is a 0 in your table. If so, this will work and make use only of internal functions of pandas, in hope that they are well optimized:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_dicts)
df2 = df2.unstack().reset_index()
df.merge(df2, left_on=['col1', 'col2'], right_on=['level_0', 'level_1'], how='left')
```

Which will result in:

```
  col1 col2 level_0 level_1  0
0   x1   y0      x1      y0  0
1   x2   y1      x2      y1  1
2   x2   y0      x2      y0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use list comprehension in the following manner:

```
df['col3'] = [dict_of_dicts[x][y] for x, y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
print(df)

  col1 col2  col3
0   x1   y0     0
1   x2   y1     1
2   x2   y0     2
```