# Python - Adding new column with mapped value from a dictionary containing a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping, lookup

I am attempting to add at least one, or even multiple columns to a dataframe from a mapped dictionary.  I have a dictionary keyed on product catalog numbers containing a list of standardized hierarchical nomenclature for that product number.  Example below.

```
dict = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"product": [1, 2, 3]})
df['catagory'] = df['product'].map(dict)
print(df)
```

I get the following result:

```
    product      catagory
0        1  [a, b, c, d]
1        2  [w, x, y, z]
2        3           NaN
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
     product     cat1     cat2     cat3     cat4
0       1          a        b       c         d
1       2          w        x       y         z
2       3         NaN      NaN     NaN       NaN
```

Or even better:

```
     product     category
0       1           d
1       2           z
2       3         NaN
```

I have been trying just to parse our one of the items from the list within the dictionary and append it to the dataframe but have only found advice for mapping dictionaries that contain one item within the list, per this [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows/32470490#32470490

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `set_index`, `apply`, `add_prefix` , `reset_index`:

```
df_out = (df.set_index('product')['catagory']
  .apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)))

df_out.columns = df_out.columns + 1

df_out.add_prefix('cat').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   product cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
0        1    a    b    c    d
1        2    w    x    y    z
2        3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

To it to the next `even better` setp:

```
(df.set_index('product')['catagory']
  .apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
  .stack(dropna=False)
  .rename('category')
  .reset_index()
  .drop('level_1',axis=1)
  .drop_duplicates()
)
```

Output:

```
   product category
0        1        a
1        1        b
2        1        c
3        1        d
4        2        w
5        2        x
6        2        y
7        2        z
8        3      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notice**:

Never use reserved words like `list`, `type`, `dict`... as variables because masking built-in functions.

So if use:

```
#dict is variable name
dict = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
#create dictionary is not possible, because dict is dictionary
print (dict(a=1, b=2))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

get error:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

and debug is very complicated. (After testing restart IDE)

So use another variable like `d` or `categories`:

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
print (dict(a=1, b=2))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

---

I think you need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"product": [1, 2, 3]})
print (df)
   product
0        1
1        2
2        3

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df1.columns = ['cat' + (str(i+1)) for i in df1.columns]
print(df1)
  cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
1    a    b    c    d
2    w    x    y    z

df2 = df.join(df1, on='product')
print (df2)
   product cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
0        1    a    b    c    d
1        2    w    x    y    z
2        3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then is possible use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df3 = df2.melt('product', value_name='category').drop('variable', axis=1)
print (df3)
    product category
0         1        a
1         2        w
2         3      NaN
3         1        b
4         2        x
5         3      NaN
6         1        c
7         2        y
8         3      NaN
9         1        d
10        2        z
11        3      NaN
```

---

```
df2 = df.set_index('product').join(df1)
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename('category')
        .reset_index()
print (df2)
    product category
0         1        a
1         1        b
2         1        c
3         1        d
4         2        w
5         2        x
6         2        y
7         2        z
8         3      NaN
9         3      NaN
10        3      NaN
11        3      NaN
```

If column `category` is in `df` solution is similar, only is necessary remove  rows with `NaN` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
df = pd.DataFrame( {"product": [1, 2, 3]})
df['category'] = df['product'].map(d)
print(df)

df1 = df.dropna(subset=['category'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1['category'].values.tolist(), index=df1['product'])
df1.columns = ['cat' + (str(i+1)) for i in df1.columns]
print(df1)
        cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
product                    
1          a    b    c    d
2          w    x    y    z

df2 = df[['product']].join(df1, on='product')
print (df2)
   product cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
0        1    a    b    c    d
1        2    w    x    y    z
2        3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

#Split product to 4 columns
df[['product']].join(
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(d.get(x['product'],[np.nan])),axis=1)
      .rename_axis(lambda x: 'cat{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)
    )
Out[187]: 
   product cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4
0        1    a    b    c    d
1        2    w    x    y    z
2        3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

#only take the last element
df['catagory'] = df.apply(lambda x: d.get(x['product'],[np.nan])[-1],axis=1)

df
Out[171]: 
   product catagory
0        1        d
1        2        z
2        3      NaN
```