# Looking up a value in a dictionary to fill an excel column in python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I'm really sorry if I word this badly.

I'm creating a program to read an excel file and manipulate that into another spreadsheet. I've accomplished this mostly with pandas. What I want to do now is from another workbook (or I was thinking a dictionary might work better) look up a wholesale price and fill a column with it. The list of products can be added to each day so I have made it so that it 'builds' the spreadsheet from scratch each time. Therefore I can't go in and save the column with the formula I want in excel. The format of what I am working on looks like this
 [image]

Every column aside from F I can populate with pandas. There might be 20 entries in the price list.

Any thoughts? Am I on the right track with a dictionary?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216489 this?

Comment: You can populate every column including column F in pandas. Open your other workbook/dictionary with pandas, modify column F with pandas, and output as a csv/xlsx file with pandas.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Was able to work it out from there. Really appreciate it.