# Pandas: Create series by mapping 2-dimensional dictionary to another series

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I'm trying to create a new series within a dataframe that maps a dictionary along two-dimensions, first matching the key, then matching the value within an array .  The existing series is a datetime and the key match is against the date and the value match is the hour (thus the new series `'dh'`)

There is a similar question for mapping a 1-dimensional array here: [Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary), but that maps the entire array to each day.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pd.date_range('1/1/2018','1/4/2018', freq = '1H', closed = 'left')})

day_hour = {1:range(48,0,-2),
            2:range(96,0,-4),
            3:range(120,0,-5) }

df['dh'] = df['datetime'].dt.day.map(day_hour)
```

Output snippet:

```
              datetime                                                 dh
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
1  2018-01-01 01:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
2  2018-01-01 02:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
3  2018-01-01 03:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
4  2018-01-01 04:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
5  2018-01-01 05:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
6  2018-01-01 06:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
7  2018-01-01 07:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
8  2018-01-01 08:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
9  2018-01-01 09:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
10 2018-01-01 10:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
11 2018-01-01 11:00:00  [48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 2...
```

Desired Output:

```
              datetime   dh
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00   48
1  2018-01-01 01:00:00   46
2  2018-01-01 02:00:00   44
3  2018-01-01 03:00:00   42
4  2018-01-01 04:00:00   40
5  2018-01-01 05:00:00   38
...
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dict is well created , you do not need map

```
df['dh']=sum(map(list,day_hour.values()),[])
```

Update

```
df['dh'] = df['datetime'].dt.day.map(day_hour)
df['new']=df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.date).cumcount()

df['dh']=df.apply(lambda x : x['dh'][x['new']],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, but can you clarify what a "well created" dict means?

Comment: @pshep123 created base on the order of your dataframe , which mean `df['datetime'].dt.day` return `[1,2,3]`, dict key should be [1,2,3]

Comment: Then it is exactly that, per the example above.  However, now I'm having trouble on the full-code (vs. this example code) and getting a ```Length of values does not match length of index``` error.

Comment: @pshep123 do we have both `2018-01-01 00:00:00` and`2018-02-01 00:00:00` in real data ?

Comment: yes - there would be multiple matches against the key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166834/discussion-between-pshep123-and-wen).

Comment: After a little tweaking (had to groupby two variables in my actual code), this did the trick!  Thanks @Wen

Answer (score 0):

I was playing golf with your problem

```
df.assign(dh=[h[t.hour] for t, h in df.values])

             datetime  dh
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00  48
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00  46
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00  44
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00  42
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00  40
...
```