# How to append duplicate multiple values to a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, append

Say I have the pandas DataFrame below:

```
       A      B      C   D
    0  foo    one    2   0
    1  foo    two    2   0
    2  foo    three  2   0
    4  bar    one    2   1
    5  bar    two    2   1
    6  bar    three  2   1
```

I want to append a column 'E' with value (aaa,bbb,ccc)according to the value of B and repeat itself for different 'A'

```
aaa=0.03
bbb=0.2
ccc=0.14
```

Expected output:

```
       A      B      C   D  E
    0  foo    one    2   0  0.03
    1  foo    two    2   0  0.2
    2  foo    three  2   0  0.14
    4  bar    one    2   1  0.03
    5  bar    two    2   1  0.2
    6  bar    three  2   1  0.14
```

I only know how to do this if I use `groupby()`to get the value of E, but how can I do this with constant numbers?

Comment: No, it's not cumcount @jezrael

Comment: It is not [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24216425) dupe?

Comment: Like `d = {'one':aaa, 'two':bbb, 'three':ccc}

df['E'] = df['B'].map(d)`

Comment: @jezrael True, thanks, I didn't know if I need to use ```map``` when I posted this question.

Comment: yop, no problem, glad can help