# How to iterate over pandas rows to make a new column using conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
index   A   ... pheno
0      0.8        0
:
500000 1.4        5
```

where pheno is a `int` between 0 and 5.

I want to iterate over the rows and check the `pheno` column and create a new column based on the value in pheno, so if pheno is 0 then the new column `class` will be 1.

so:

```
index   A  ...  pheno  class
0      0.8        0      1
:
500000 1.4        5      3
```

I know how to do this using `df.iterrows` and `if/elif` but was wondering if there was a quicker way than generating 5 elif statements for each `pheno` value?

Just to add - in some cases my `pheno` column can be up to 13+ values hence why I think `if/elif` are inefficient.

Comment: Do you need [map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24216425) ?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Yes ```map``` is what I needed! Thank you!