# Using a dictionary to map specific values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating through a dataframe and pulling out specific lines and then enriching those lines with some other elements. I have a dictionary that has the following definition mapping:

```
testdir = {0: 'zero', 40: 'forty', 60: 'sixty', 80: 'eighty'}
```

When i pull out a specific line from the original dataframe which looks like this

```
a   b   c      x   str
0  0   0   0  100.0  aaaa
```

i want the str cell to now be set to the string value of column c which is 0 so

output should be

```
a   b   c      x   str
0  0   0   0  100.0  zero
```

and then after meeting some other conditions a new line is pulled out from the original dataframe and the output should be

```
a   b   c      x   str
0  0   0   0  100.0  zero
3  4  30  60  100.0  sixty
```

i tried to use the map() method so something like'

```
df['str'][-1] = df['c'][-1].map(testdir)
```

but i'm erroring all over the place!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is intended for `pd.Series`, so if you can, just map the entire column when it is fully populated, that way you avoid the oevrhead of multiple calls to `map`:

```
df['str'] = df.c.map(testdir)
```

---

```
print(df)

   a   b   c      x    str
0  0   0   0  100.0   zero
3  4  30  60  100.0  sixty
```

---

Note that, to correctly index the dataframe on a single cell, and map with the dictionary, you need something like:

```
testdir[df.iat[-1, 2]]
```

Chained indexing as `df['c'][-1]` [is discouraged in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), and has a negative effect when assigning, which is that your not updating the original dataframe, since it returns a copy.