# Pandas Change Categorical day_of_week column to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dayofweek

i have a categorical column in a dataframe with the days of the week

```
name      day_of_week
example 1 Monday
example 2 Monday
example 3 Wednesday
example 4 Monday
example 5 Friday
example 6 Monday
example 7 Sunday
```

but i need to change it to datetime format with the corresponding values and can't seem to do it

```
name      day_of_week
example 1 0
example 2 0
example 3 2
example 4 0
example 5 4
example 6 0
example 7 6
```

is there a simple one line way to do it?

```
dataframe['day_of_week'] = dataframe['day_of_week'].??
```

Comment: Do you need [map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24216425) ?

Comment: not sure. i need to convert it from categorical  to datetime64[ns]

Comment: convert_to_number = {Monday:0, Tuesday:1, Wednesday:2, Thursday:3, Friday:4, Saturday:5, Sunday:6} 
dataframe['day_of_week'] = dataframe['day_of_week'].map(convert_to_number) i tried something like this but can't seem to make it work

Comment: there is error?