# pandas - insert value into a new column based on a list of dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of **dictionary**

```
items = [{'name':'Fruit','title':'Apple','id':'1'},
{'name':'Fruit','title':'Banana','id':'1'},
{'name':'Vegetable','title':'Tomato','id':'2'},
{'name':'Vegetable','title':'Onion','id':'2'}]
```

and I have a **dataframe**

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'Name': {0: 'Banana', 1: 'Apple', 2: 'Orange', 3: 'Tomato', 4: 'Onion'},'Price': {0: 25, 1: 20, 2: 10, 3: 26, 4: 45},'Kg': {0: 1, 1: 25, 2: 3, 3: 55, 4: 10}})
```

[image]

Now I need to map the title in next column, if the value not exist in dict, it can be Empty

**Expected output:**

[image]

What I have tried is

```
df["Title"] = df["Name"].map(lambda x : for i in items[name] == x)
```

[Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary)

But its not working as items is a list of dictonary.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your list into a single dict and use that to map.

```
df['Title'] = df['Name'].map({i['title']:i['name'] for i in items})
```

Comment: it shows KeyError :name, also what does this mean i['title']:i['name']

Comment: Please change variable i to k in the answer

Comment: @jones sorry had a typo there