# Loading STATA file: Categorial values must be unique

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load the `.dta` file behind this [zip file](http://ceprdata.org/wp-content/cps/data/cepr_org_2014.zip) into `pandas`. However, I immediately get an error. I also have stata at my command, but since the error message doesn't tell me something more, like the faulty column, I have no clue what to do.

How can I load the file into `pandas`?

```
>>> df = pd.read_stata('cepr_org_2014.dta')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/stata.py", line 69, in read_stata
    order_categoricals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/stata.py", line 1315, in data
    cat_data.categories = categories
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 442, in _set_categories
    categories = self._validate_categories(categories)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 437, in _validate_categories
    raise ValueError('Categorical categories must be unique')
ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique
```

Comment: What are the columns named? Do you have repeats someplace? Also, `pandas` is now at 0.16.2, you may wish to consider upgrading, in case it's an issue with pandas itself.

Comment: @MattDMo I don't know. I looked into that file, and the column names seem to be fine. There may be repeats, my Stata knowledge isn't good enough to tell quickly. Basically this question is about exactly finding that solution, as `pandas` seems to be cheap on error information.

Comment: debugging with ipdb:


        ipdb> categories.get_duplicates()
        ['Nonrelative']

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this, @FooBar? I'm having the same issue, and I don't have Stata installed on my computer to fix it in the .dta file.

Comment: @WillAdler the `convert_categorical` did the trick for me to load the data in, then you can do whatever you want with `pandas`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have mentioned that that's not a great option for me. Turning that off seems to toss the categorical labels in the data, which I need. For instance, I have columns consisting of ordered categorical strings. If convert_categoricals == False, then they are converted to their integer rank, but the labels don't seem to be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Load this with `pandas.read_stata('cepr_org_2014.dta', convert_categoricals=False, convert_missing=True)` and have a look at what the data looks like.
Optionally debugging with ipdb as commented in the question shows there's a duplicate category in your data.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Can only disagree with that, the question is how to load that .dta into pandas dataframe and setting convert_logicals to False makes that possible.

Comment: If you've done that with the file referenced in the question, then **say that** and post all of the code necessary to do it, with an explanation. As it stands, you are basically saying, "*Try this, it may work.*" which **is** a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. Edited the answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into a similar problem recently, and it seems to be no structured solution out there (including the pandas documentation I'm afraid), so this is my attempt at a more or less re-usable answer.

The file link does not work any more though, and I assume that it's the same file as the `cepr_org_2014.dta` on the [CPS ORG Data page](https://ceprdata.org/cps-uniform-data-extracts/cps-outgoing-rotation-group/cps-org-data/).

#### Method 1

Recent pandas versions report more detailed error messages for this particular problem ([pandas-dev/pandas Issue #13923](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13923)). So when I tried the same command, this is the error message:

```
ValueError: 
Value labels for column smsastat14 are not unique. These cannot be converted to
pandas categoricals.

Either read the file with `convert_categoricals` set to False or use the
low level interface in `StataReader` to separately read the values and the
value_labels.

The repeated labels are:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bridgeport-Stamford-Norwalk, CT
Hartford-West Hartford-East Hartford, CT
Portland-South Portland, ME
Burlington-South Burlington, VT
Worcester, MA-CT
Bangor, ME
```

It means that in the column `smsastat14`, multiple data codes have been mapped to the same labels. I do not know if this is against Stata best practice, but there are a lot of datasets in the wild with the same problem.

(By the way, I was very puzzled by the sentence `` use the low level interface in `StataReader` to separately read the values and the value_labels ``, since nowhere in the documentation that I am aware is this kind of method mentioned. The [`pandas.io.stata.StataReader` doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.stata.StataReader.value_labels.html) seem to all focus on creating Stata datasets instead of reading one.)

Now, if you use the `convert_categoricals=False` flag, you will be able to get a DataFrame, but with numerical codes, like this:

```py
df["smsastat14"]

# 0             NaN
# 1             NaN
# 2             NaN
# 3             NaN
# 4             NaN
#            ...   
# 317051    46520.0
# 317052    26180.0
# 317053    26180.0
# 317054    26180.0
# 317055    26180.0
# Name: smsastat14, Length: 317056, dtype: float32
```

The missing piece is how to convert the codes back to its labels. Here is one simple way how you could do it: (map seems to be much faster than replace, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/10668706))

```py
import pandas as pd

with pd.io.stata.StataReader("cepr_org_2014.dta") as sr:
    value_labels = sr.value_labels()

df = pd.read_stata(
    "cepr_org_2014.dta",
    convert_categoricals=False,
)

for col in df:
    if col in value_labels:
        df[col].replace(value_labels[col], inplace=True)
```

Now you have the values. Note that is is object type, so you may want to convert it into categorical or string before conducting analysis.

```py
df["smsastat14"]

# 0                        NaN
# 1                        NaN
# 2                        NaN
# 3                        NaN
# 4                        NaN
#                  ...        
# 317051    Urban Honolulu, HI
# 317052         Honolulu, HI*
# 317053         Honolulu, HI*
# 317054         Honolulu, HI*
# 317055         Honolulu, HI*
# Name: smsastat14, Length: 317056, dtype: object
```

#### Method 2

Another slightly more involved way is to modify the `value_labels` dictionary directly, such that their (ordered) categorical structure is preserved, perfectly for unmodified columns, partially for modified columns. **Since this is undocumented behaviour, please note that is could be subject to change in the future versions.**

First look at the `value_labels` and find the repeated values.

```py
with pd.io.stata.StataReader("cepr_org_2014.dta") as sr:
    value_labels = sr.value_labels()
    print(value_labels["smsastat14"])
```

Since it is a dictionary with non-unique values, I have yet to find ways of locating them other than pasting the output into a text editor and search. After replacing all repeated values in this column, another column popped up, so we deal with that as well.

The importing code:

```py
with pd.io.stata.StataReader("cepr_org_2014.dta") as sr:
    value_labels = sr.value_labels()
    value_labels["smsastat14"][71950] = "Bridgeport-Stamford-Norwalk, CT (1)"
    value_labels["smsastat14"][73450] = "Hartford-West Hartford-East Hartford, CT (1)"
    value_labels["smsastat14"][76750] = "Portland-South Portland, ME (1)"
    value_labels["smsastat14"][72400] = "Burlington-South Burlington, VT (1)"
    value_labels["smsastat14"][79600] = "Worcester, MA-CT (1)"
    value_labels["smsastat14"][70750] = "Bangor, ME (1)"
    value_labels["reltoref"][12] = "Nonrelative (1)"
    df = sr.read()
```

And the columns preserved their original types except our little tweaks:

```py
df["smsastat14"]

# 0                        NaN
# 1                        NaN
# 2                        NaN
# 3                        NaN
# 4                        NaN
#                  ...        
# 317051    Urban Honolulu, HI
# 317052         Honolulu, HI*
# 317053         Honolulu, HI*
# 317054         Honolulu, HI*
# 317055         Honolulu, HI*
# Name: smsastat14, Length: 317056, dtype: category
# Categories (326, object): [0.0 < 'Abilene, TX' < 'Akron, OH' < 'Albany, GA' ... 'Rochester-Dover, NH-ME' < 'Springfield, MA-CT' < 'Waterbury, CT' < 'Worcester, MA-CT (1)']
```