# python- How to update a column using value in another column as key to a defined dictionary in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a dictionary which looks like this: `di = {1: "A", 2: "B"}`

I would like to apply it to the "col3" column of a dataframe similar to using value in "col1" as key to `di`:

```
     col1   col2   col3
0       w      a     U
1       1      2     V
2       2    NaN     W
```

to get:

```
     col1   col2   col3
0       w      a     U
1       1      2     A
2       2    NaN     B
```

How can I best do this? All answers I found were to [replace columns considering them as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict).

Comment: It appears either `"col1"` in the text is wrong or the example (with "col3" changed) is wrong....

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the mapping on `col1` and fill the missing values with the values in `col3`:

```
df.col3 = df.col1.map(di).fillna(df.col3)
```