# Replace values in pandas Series with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I want to replace values in a pandas `Series` using a dictionary. I'm following @DSM's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict) like so:

```
s = Series(['abc', 'abe', 'abg'])
d = {'b': 'B'}
s.replace(d)
```

But this has no effect:

```
0    abc
1    abe
2    abg
dtype: object
```

The [documentation](http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/pandas/doc/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) explains the required format of the dictionary for `DataFrames` (i.e. nested dicts with top level keys corresponding to column names) but I can't see anything specific for `Series`.

Comment: you need to assign back the result or pass param `inplace=True` e.g. `s = s.replace(d)` or `s.replace(d, inplace=True)`, virtually all pandas ops return a copy so you either want to assign back or pass `inplace=True` where supported

Comment: Try this: `s.replace(d, regex=True)`

Comment: @EdChum, `s.replace(d, inplace=True)` - doesn't do desired replacement - test it...

Comment: @MaxU That worked - thanks. Hidden assumption - I was looking for regex matching - not exact matching. Didn't realise it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `regex=True` parameter:

```
In [37]: s.replace(d, regex=True)
Out[37]:
0    aBc
1    aBe
2    aBg
dtype: object
```

As you have already [found out yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075106/replace-values-in-pandas-series-with-dictionary/40075212#comment67423617_40075106) - it's a RegEx replacement and it won't work as you expected:

```
In [36]: s.replace(d)
Out[36]:
0    abc
1    abe
2    abg
dtype: object
```

this is working as expected:

```
In [38]: s.replace({'abc':'ABC'})
Out[38]:
0    ABC
1    abe
2    abg
dtype: object
```

Comment: Because then it assumes you want to replace the *value* `"b"` with `"B"`, but the value `b` is not in the Series. However, `b` is contained within the strings that make up the values...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yep, thank you! I've already realized that. :)