# Pandas replace/dictionary slowness

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dictionary

Please help me understand why this "replace from dictionary" operation is slow in Python/Pandas:

```
# Series has 200 rows and 1 column
# Dictionary has 11269 key-value pairs
series.replace(dictionary, inplace=True)
```

Dictionary lookups should be O(1). Replacing a value in a column should be O(1). Isn't this a vectorized operation? Even if it's not vectorized, iterating 200 rows is only 200 iterations, so how can it be slow?

Here is a SSCCE demonstrating the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Initialize dummy data
dictionary = {}
orig = []
for x in range(11270):
    dictionary[x] = 'Some string ' + str(x)
for x in range(200):
    orig.append(random.randint(1, 11269))
series = pd.Series(orig)

# The actual operation we care about
print('Starting...')
series.replace(dictionary, inplace=True)
print('Done.')
```

Running that command takes more than 1 second on my machine, which is 1000's of times longer than expected to perform <1000 operations.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, and define what you mean by "slow".  I have no performance issues when I try to replicate your setup, with the replace taking ~200ms.

Comment: Edited OP with SSCCE. Is ~1ms per operation really the expected performance when working with Python?

Comment: Relevant post which touches on why and when there's a difference in performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933438/19123103

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks like [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) has a bit of overhead, and explicitly telling the Series what to do via [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) yields the best performance:

```
series = series.map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x,x))
```

If you're sure that all keys are in your dictionary you can get a very slight performance boost by not creating a lambda, and directly supplying the `dictionary.get` function.  Any keys that are not present will return `NaN` via this method, so beware:

```
series = series.map(dictionary.get)
```

You can also supply just the dictionary itself, but this appears to introduce a bit of overhead:

```
series = series.map(dictionary)
```

**Timings**

Some timing comparisons using your example data:

```
%timeit series.map(dictionary.get)
10000 loops, best of 3: 124 µs per loop

%timeit series.map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x,x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 150 µs per loop

%timeit series.map(dictionary)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.45 ms per loop

%timeit series.replace(dictionary)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop
```

Comment: Any idea what causes so much overhead? Using `.replace(dictionary)` on my dataframe was causing my notebook to crash after a decent wait but doing `.map(dictionary.get)` takes under a second. It's very strange to me that there could be orders of magnitude of overhead in a built-in function in the dataframe; I'd have expected `.map` to be worse than `.replace`.

Comment: `.replace `can do incomplete substring matches, while `.map` requires complete values to be supplied in the dictionary

Comment: Will also add that for DataFrame, use `applymap` instead: `df = df.applymap(dictionary.get)`.

Comment: I'm curious why your `.map(dictionary)` results are so off from @Shaurya Uppal's results.

Answer (score 4):

`.replace`can do incomplete substring matches, while `.map` requires complete values to be supplied in the dictionary (or it returns NaNs). The fast but generic solution (that can handle substring) should first use `.replace` on a dict of all possible values (obtained e.g. with `.value_counts().index`) and then go over all rows of the Series with this dict and `.map`. This combo can handle for instance special national characters replacements (full substrings) on 1m-row columns in a quarter of a second, where `.replace` alone would take 15.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @root: I did a benchmarking again and found different results on pandas v1.1.4

**Found `series.map(dictionary)` fastest it also returns NaN is key not present**

[image: Benchmark]

Comment: I also get faster results with `map(dictionary)` rather than `map(dictionary.get)` on Python 3.10.5 and Pandas 1.4.2.
In my case it's 6 times faster

Comment: @Ludecan 6 times that is wow. In the above screenshot, I got a gain of 1.9x times.

Comment: `map(dictionary)` returns `NaN` if a key is not found in the `dictionary`, so be cautious