# Efficient way to map value of pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have panda data frame df:

```
Product_Code Date  Price
A            Jan    10.5
A            Dec    11.2
B            jun    8.1
...
```

Then there is dictionary which map every product_code to a unique product_Id like {(A:1},(B:2),...}. I want to apply this map to the df and convert product_code to product_Id:

```
df_new=df.replace({"Product_Code": mapp})
```

However it is very slow and take a lot of time for this conversion. Is there a better and efficient way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: `df.Product_Code = df.Product_Code.map(mapp)`

Comment: Well, there *is* Series.map https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: `df['Product_Code'].replace(mapp)`

Comment: Consider using map, here is an excellent link comparing efficiency https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012339/using-replace-efficiently-in-pandas