# Check if value is present in dataframe and find it within a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, email, dictionary

Assuming a dataframe

```
Market | Status | Team |
-------|--------|------|
Chicago|   1    | Tom  |
Chicago|   1    | Tom  |
SF Bay |   3    | Julia|
SF Bay |   1    | Julia|
SF Bay |   1    | Julia|
```

And a dictionary

```
Team = {"Tom": "tom@email.com", "Julia": "Julia@email.com", "Carol": "carol@email.com"}
```

I want to get each team members specific dataframe, convert it to HTML and email it to them. I can get the dataframes individually that I need and then `df.to_html()` it. In the case above, `Carol` is in the dictionary, but not within the dataframe, so I don't want her to receive an email.

I've tried

```
for i in Team:
    df[df['Team'].str.contains(i)]
    Mail = df[df['Team'].isin([i])]
    ...
    #send an email
```

But this would then send an email with a blank dataframe to `Carol`. How can I iterate through easily and get only those names that are present from my dictionary and then utilize the dictionary email value to send an email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map`, convert the `Team` column to a column of email addresses, and then use a `groupby` to get each team member's `DataFrame` separately, using a dictionary comprehension.

```
df['Team'] = df['Team'].map(Team)
df

    Market  Status             Team
0  Chicago       1    tom@email.com
1  Chicago       1    tom@email.com
2   SF Bay       3  Julia@email.com
3   SF Bay       1  Julia@email.com
4   SF Bay       1  Julia@email.com
```

```
df_dict = {i : g for i, g in df.groupby('Team')}

df_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['Julia@email.com', 'tom@email.com'])  # look ma, no Carol
```

Note that [`map` scales better than `replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42012366/4909087). After this, you can iterate over each key-value pair, and dispatch:

```
for email, df in df_dict.items():
    data = df.to_html()
    ... # dispatch `data` to `email`
```

For more info on how to dispatch email through python using the SMTP protocol, refer to the [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) module in the standard library.

---

If you want to keep the `Name` column, you can combine the `groupby` and `map` step together, and simplify your solution:

```
df_dict = {i : g for i, g in df.groupby(df.Team.map(Team))}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there any way to maintain their names so I can place them inside the email?

Comment: @ATCH_torn Of course! It's even simpler, in fact. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That works great! One last question. Can I then take the name and append it to the dictionary? Ideally I'd like to have `name: email, df` all in one fell swoop.

Comment: @ATCH_torn Well, you could do so. The key is the name and the value is a list/tuple. You could choose to create a new dict by iterating over `df_dict`. For each value, `df.Team.unique()` gives you the name. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace` :-)

```
df.Team.replace(d,inplace=True)
df
Out[176]: 
    Market  Status             Team
0  Chicago       1    tom@email.com
1  Chicago       1    tom@email.com
2    SFBay       3  Julia@email.com
3    SFBay       1  Julia@email.com
4    SFBay       1  Julia@email.com
```