# python: replace values in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 3, 'www', 'abc'],[4,5,6, 'ppp', 'def'], [6,7,8, 'qqq', 'ggg'], [11,22,33, 'fff', 'mmm']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

d = {'www': 'www_replaced', 'def': 'def_replaced', 'fff': 'fff_replaced' }
df.replace(d, value=None, inplace=True)
```

As a result, `dataframe` is updated accordingly:

```
>>> df
    A   B   C             D             E
0   1   2   3  www_replaced           abc
1   4   5   6           ppp  def_replaced
2   6   7   8           qqq           ggg
3  11  22  33  fff_replaced           mmm
>>>
```

However, I'd like to use `map()` function of `pandas` on both columns D and E for two reasons:

- I read that in general `map` is faster then `replace`
- I can do something like this: `df[column] = df[column].map(d).fillna('Unknown')`

I could run it twice, e.g. :

```
df['D'] = df['D'].map(d).fillna('Unknown')
df['E'] = df['E'].map(d).fillna('Unknown')
```

But is there a way to do change values in multiple columns with `map` in one command?

Comment: No as [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is only a series function. For speed, It depends on the size of your data, [map is roughly 4 times faster for 30k rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012339/using-replace-efficiently-in-pandas) and it is unclear what your best usecase should be. If you want to `map`, use a for loop on the columns

Comment: @modesitt, thanks for feedback. I will use the loop. My dataset is ~50-60K row

Comment: If you need to do this on many columns, then `df[list_of_cols].stack().map(d).fillna('Unknown').unstack()` will barely outperform the simple loop over columns for smaller DataFrames (<3000 rows).

Comment: If you are writing a loop, I think it's more elegant to use `apply`. Don't think performance wise it will be much worse/better: `df[['D', 'E']] = df[['D', 'E']].apply(lambda x: x.map(d)).fillna('Unknown')`. Although I think for bigger datasets (500k >) the solution of ALollz will do better.