# How to get columns containing names of pre-defined equivalence classes of values in each row of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

```
# import package
import pandas as pd
```

---

### The problem

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'row1': ['a', 'A', 'B', 'b'],
        'row2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'row3': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'D']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['col'+str(x) for x in range(4)])
```

which looks like:

[image]

I also have a list of equivalence classes. Each equivalence class consists of items which are taken as equivalent.

```
equivalenceClasses={'classA':['a','A'],
                    'classB':['b','B'],
                    'classC':['c','C'],
                    'classD':['d','D']}
```

I would like to create a dataframe in which the *rows in the above dataframe are replaced by the names of the equivalence classes the letters in the row belong to*. (Each equivalence class should appear no more than once in a row, and we should use `NaN`s to post-pad rows in which not all columns are fille by a name of an equivalence class). Ie I want this output:

[image]

---

### My method

I achieve the goal by:

```
def differentClasses(colvalues):
    return list(set([equivalenceClassName for colvalue in colvalues
                                          for equivalenceClassName, equivalenceClass in zip(equivalenceClasses.keys(),
                                                                                   equivalenceClasses.values())
                                          if colvalue in equivalenceClass]))
```

([On list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520), [on nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list).)

```
df['classes'] = df.apply(lambda row : differentClasses(row['col'+str(x)] for x in range(4)), axis = 1)
```

(Influenced by [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/).)

The `df` at this point looks like this:

[image]

Finish by:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(df['classes'].tolist(),index=df.index,columns=['classcol'+str(x) for x in range(4)])
```

`result_df` is the desired output above.

---

### The question

Is there a more standard way of doing this? Something like:

```
df.equivalenceClassify(equivalenceClassList)
```

and I get my output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need create the new dict based on your original `equivalenceClasses`, then just do `replace`

```
from collections import ChainMap
d = dict(ChainMap(*[dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x , y in equivalenceClasses.items()]))
df = df.replace(d)
Out[299]: 
        col0    col1    col2    col3
row1  classA  classA  classB  classB
row2  classA  classB  classC  classD
row3  classA  classB  classD  classD
```

Then

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,1))
Out[307]: 
        col0    col1    col2    col3
row1  classA     NaN  classB     NaN
row2  classA  classB  classC  classD
row3  classA  classB  classD     NaN
```

Comment: Maybe on a large dataframe, could we do better than .replace()? Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012339/using-replace-efficiently-in-pandas) currently...

Comment: @zabop yes , we could you can try create the data , then convert it back via pivot ~