# .replace codes will not replace column with new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a column in python, and create a new column using python.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\seqadv.csv') 
print (df)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WT_RESIDUE':['']})
codes = {'ALA':'A', 'ARG':'R', 'ASN':'N', 'ASP':'D', 'CYS':'C', 'GLU':'E', 'GLN':'Q', 'GLY':'G', 'HIS':'H', 'ILE':'I', 'LEU':'L', 'LYS':'K', 'MET':'M', 'PHE':'F', 'PRO':'P', 'SER':'S', 'THR':'T', 'TRP':'W', 'TYR':'Y', 'VAL':'V'}
df['MUTATION_CODE'] = df['WT_RESIDUE'].replace(codes)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\output.csv')
```

I tried this, but it will not create a new column no matter what I do.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzYsl.png)

Comment: Can you please explain what column you are reading and what column you want to derive from it. Providing sample input and output will help. Please provide text and not images.

Comment: does the image answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you made a silly mistake

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\seqadv.csv') 
print (df)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WT_RESIDUE':['']}) # Why do you have this line?
codes = {'ALA':'A', 'ARG':'R', 'ASN':'N', 'ASP':'D', 'CYS':'C', 'GLU':'E', 'GLN':'Q', 'GLY':'G', 'HIS':'H', 'ILE':'I', 'LEU':'L', 'LYS':'K', 'MET':'M', 'PHE':'F', 'PRO':'P', 'SER':'S', 'THR':'T', 'TRP':'W', 'TYR':'Y', 'VAL':'V'}
df['MUTATION_CODE'] = df['WT_RESIDUE'].replace(codes)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\output.csv')
```

Try removing the line with the comment. AFAIK, it is reinitializing your `DataFrame` and thus the `WT_RESIDUE` column becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

Considering sample from provided input.
We can use map function to map the keys of dict to existing column and persist corresponding values in new column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'WT_RESIDUE':['ALA', "REMARK", 'VAL', "LYS"]
})
codes = {'ALA':'A', 'ARG':'R', 'ASN':'N', 'ASP':'D', 'CYS':'C', 'GLU':'E', 'GLN':'Q', 'GLY':'G', 'HIS':'H', 'ILE':'I', 'LEU':'L', 'LYS':'K', 'MET':'M', 'PHE':'F', 'PRO':'P', 'SER':'S', 'THR':'T', 'TRP':'W', 'TYR':'Y', 'VAL':'V'}
df['MUTATION_CODE'] = df.WT_RESIDUE.map(codes)
```

**Input**

```
    WT_RESIDUE
0   ALA
1   REMARK
2   VAL
3   LYS
```

**Output**

```
    WT_RESIDUE  MUTATION_CODE
0   ALA          A
1   REMARK       NaN
2   VAL          V
3   LYS          K
```

Comment: Using `map` is the same as `replace`.  Prior to version 19.2, a difference in speed was pointed but it seems to be no longer the case. Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012339/using-replace-efficiently-in-pandas