# Faster way of remapping dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to `remap` data from *dictionary* to the respective values in dataframe and I am successful in it.

It is fine when I am using few thousands of data but gets radically slow and sometimes never ending if I try to do it with few millions of data.

Here is the code I am using and works fine for less data:

```
def remap(data,dict_labels):
    for field,values in dict_labels.items():
        data.replace({field:values},inplace=True)
    print("DONE")
    return data
dataframe1 = remap(df,dataDict)
```

Is there any efficient way of using something else for the same task so that it is faster for large data?

Comment: Why do you need the for loop? Isn't what you are doing the same as just `data.replace(dict_labels, inplace=True)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985566/pandas-replace-dictionary-slowness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pd.DataFrame.applymap` for this:

```
dataframe1 = df.applymap(dict_labels.get).fillna(df)
```

Note we use `fillna` to recover unmapped values.

As per the documentation:

> DataFrame.**applymap**(*func*)
>
> Apply a function to a DataFrame that is intended to operate
>   elementwise, i.e. like doing map(func, series) for each series in the
>   DataFrame

Performance note: [Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently)