# Conditionally replace values in pandas dataframe - numpy where behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, where-clause

My goal is to replace certain values in a **pandas** dataframe, based on a condition.

I have discovered that the ***numpy*** **where** method expects the first argument to be an array of boolean values, and the following works:

```
def evaluate_array(array_to_evaluate):
    output_array = []
    for elem in array_to_evaluate:
        if elem is None:
            output_array.append(True)
        else:
            output_array.append(False)
    return output_array


df['property'] = np.where(
    evaluate_array(df['property']), 
    'The value is None', 
    df.property
)
```

**Question:**

There must be a better way to express the lines of code above! I have tried the following:

```
df.loc[df.property is None, 'property'] = 'None'
```

but I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

[the accepted solution to which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611728/pandas-keyerror-cannot-use-a-single-bool-to-index-into-setitem) is as long winded as my own working code!

**EDIT:**
A great solution offered in the comments below works for my situation as follows:

```
df = df.fillna(value={'property':'The value is None'})
```

or even more readable:

```
df['property'].fillna('The value is None', inplace=True)
```

**EDIT2:**
Also, please see the accepted answer below for another great solution

Comment: does [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) not fit the bill here?

Comment: Thank you, @AsishM. I have confirmed that there is a setting of .fillna that works for me. Will add it to my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
>>> df['property'] = df['property'].fillna('The value is None')
```

Or alternatively, if None is `str` you can simply do replace:

```
>>> df['property'] = df['property'].replace('None','The value is None')
```

Comment: even better `df['property'].fillna('The value is None', inplace=True)`