# Fast way to replace value in sparse dataframe with value from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very sparse dataframe `df` such as this:

```
       Apples Bananas Pineapple Mango
Mary   Apples     NaN       NaN   NaN
Jane      NaN Bananas       NaN   NaN
Diego     NaN     NaN       NaN Mango
Guido     NaN     NaN Pineapple   NaN
```

and I would like to build a dictionary `d` such as

```
d = {'Apples':3, 'Bananas':1, 'Pineapple':2, 'Mango': 15}
```

to obtain

```
       Apples Bananas Pineapple Mango
Mary        3     NaN       NaN   NaN
Jane      NaN       1       NaN   NaN
Diego     NaN     NaN       NaN    15
Guido     NaN     NaN         2   NaN
```

I can do

```
df.to_sparse().replace(d)
```

but it's been over 30' and no output yet. My dataframe has 10000 rows times 1500 columns, the dataframe is originally 135MB, that becomes 850kB after to_sparse(). Is there any faster way?

Comment: `df.replace(d)`?

Comment: Hi all, clearly replace(d) is not working for me. I am reopening the question with focus on an alternative, more performing solution than replace(d)

Comment: @famargar - If it is very sparse, use `df = df.stack().map(d).unstack()`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - can you reopen this? Or can I reopen?

Comment: @jezrael It is a dupe, so answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20250771/2901002), also with timings if you like.

Comment: Let me know when you post it so I can upvote.

Comment: Thank you all! I guess we should clean up the comments after the edits. Removing mines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT by changed question - you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` with `MultiIndex` - (`NaN`s values are removed) -  with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and then for reshape back [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
np.random.seed(1235)
N = 1000
d = {'Apples':3, 'Bananas':1, 'Pineapple':2, 'Mango': 15}
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(d.keys()) + [np.nan], 
                  size=(N, N), 
                  p=(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.92)))
#print (df)

In [227]: %timeit df.replace(d)
1 loop, best of 3: 661 ms per loop

In [228]: %timeit df.stack().map(d).unstack()
1 loop, best of 3: 381 ms per loop
```