# Pandas replace, multi column criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace values in a Pandas data frame, based on certain criteria on multiple columns. For a single column criteria this can be done very elegantly with a dictionary (e.g. [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0:1, 1:1, 2:2}, 'col2': {0:10, 1:20, 2:20}})

rdict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
df2 = df.replace({"col1": rdict})
```

Input `df`:

```
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     1    20
2     2    20
```

Resulting `df2`:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    10
1    a    20
2    b    20
```

I'm trying to extend this to criteria over multiple columns (e.g. `where col1==1, col2==10` -> replace). For a single criteria this can be done like:

```
df3=df.copy()
df3.loc[((df['col1']==1)&(df['col2']==10)), 'col1'] = 'c'
```

Which results in a `df3`:

```
  col1  col2
0    c    10
1    1    20
2    2    20
```

My real life problem has a large number of criteria, which would involve a large number of `df3.loc[((criteria1)&(criteria2)), column] = value` calls, which is far less elegant the the replacement using a dictionary as a "lookup table". Is it possible to extend the elegant solution (`df2 = df.replace({"col1": rdict})`) to a setup where values in one column are replaced by criteria based on multiple columns?

---

An example of what I'm trying to achieve (although in my real life case the number of criteria is a *lot* larger):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2}, 'col2': {0:10, 1:20, 2:10, 3:20}})

df3=df.copy()
df3.loc[((df['col1']==1)&(df['col2']==10)), 'col1'] = 'a'
df3.loc[((df['col1']==1)&(df['col2']==20)), 'col1'] = 'b'
df3.loc[((df['col1']==2)&(df['col2']==10)), 'col1'] = 'c'
df3.loc[((df['col1']==2)&(df['col2']==20)), 'col1'] = 'd'
```

Input `df`:

```
0     1    10
1     1    20
2     2    10
3     2    20
```

Resulting `df3`:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    10
1    b    20
2    c    10
3    d    20
```

Comment: can you add a reproducible input data set and your desired data set?

Comment: Can you give an example dataset that is more close to your more real-life problem?

Comment: I'll update the question to include a more realistic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `merge`.

Suppose your df looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1}, 'col2': {0:10, 1:20, 2:10, 3:20, 4: 20, 5:10}})

    col1 col2
0   1    10
1   1    20
2   2    10
3   2    20
4   2    20
5   1    10
```

And your conditional replacement can be represented as another dataframe:

```
df_replace

  col1  col2    val
0   1   10      a
1   1   20      b
2   2   10      c
3   2   20      d

(As OP (Bart) pointed out, you can save this in a csv file.)
```

Then you can use

```
df = df.merge(df_replace, on=["col1", "col2"], how="left")

    col1    col2    val
0   1       10      a
1   1       20      b
2   2       10      c
3   2       20      d
4   2       20      d
5   1       10      a
```

Then you just need to drop `col1`.

As MaxU pointed out, there could be rows that does not get replaced and resulting in `NaN`. We can use a line like

```
df["val"] = df["val"].combine_first(df["col1"])
```

to fill in values from `col1` if the resulting values after merge is `NaN`.

Comment: Great, this will work. I can create `df_replace` from (for example) a CSV file where the conditions/replacements are defined, to keep the code clean.

Comment: @Bart that is a good idea to keep it in another csv file! Let me add it.

Comment: You will still need to take care of those rows that will not be replaced...

Comment: @MaxU it is a left merge so it shall be fine. The value on `df` that does not matched will be preserved.

Comment: @MaxU, is that why you deleted your answer? It seemed like a perfectly fine solution as well. In my case all combinations of `col1` and `col2` are guaranteed (*famous last words..*) to map to a new value.

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

Source DF:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     1    10
2     1    20
3     1    20
4     2    10
5     2    20
6     3    30
```

Conditions & Replacements DF:

```
In [121]: cond
Out[121]:
   col1  col2 repl
1     1    20    b
2     2    10    c
0     1    10    a
3     2    20    d
```

Solution:

```
In [121]: res = df.merge(cond, how='left')
```

yields:

```
In [122]: res
Out[122]:
   col1  col2 repl
0     1    10    a
1     1    10    a
2     1    20    b
3     1    20    b
4     2    10    c
5     2    20    d
6     3    30  NaN   # <-- NOTE


In [123]: res['col1'] = res.pop('repl').fillna(res['col1'])

In [124]: res
Out[124]:
  col1  col2
0    a    10
1    a    10
2    b    20
3    b    20
4    c    10
5    d    20
6    3    30
```

Comment: As mentioned, my real life problem has a lot of different conditions like `cond = "col1==1 and col2==10"`, unfortunately I don't see how this solves my problem.

Comment: @Bart, OK, you have multiple conditions, but do you have a single replacement dict or multiple?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand "but do you have a single replacement dict or multiple"; I have multiple criteria, which all map to a different replacement value.

Comment: Interesting solution, this might work well if I base `cond` on (for example) an input CSV file where the conditions and replacements are defined. I'll give it a try, unless someone posts a more elegant solution, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This method is likely to be more efficient than `pandas` functionality, as it relies on `numpy` arrays and dictionary mappings.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0:1, 1:1, 2:2, 3:2}, 'col2': {0:10, 1:20, 2:10, 3:20}})

rdict = {(1, 10): 'a', (1, 20): 'b', (2, 10): 'c', (2, 20): 'd'}

df['col1'] = list(map(rdict.get, [(x[0], x[1]) for x in df1[['c1', 'c2']].values]))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the same results as the `df3.loc[((df['col1']==1)&(df['col2']==10)), 'col1'] = 'c'`, which only replaces values in a single column based on a criterium over multiple columns

Comment: @Bart, what about this solution?

Comment: That's great, I like it as it uses the same (sort of) method with dictionaries for the replacement (like the `df.replace({"col1": rdict})` method for a single column criteria). I have to see if the difference in performance is relevant in my case, if so this might be my preferred solution.

Comment: I coded a quick benchmark, this actually seems to be slower (factor ~3.5)... (https://pastebin.com/zSEwJaYR, see benchmark results on the bottom).

Comment: @Bart, thanks for taking the effort to benchmark. I've changed my logic very slightly to use a list comprehension (small speed up). Where you lose with the `df` merge method is creation of `convert_df`. Including set-up costs of `convert_df` and `convert_dict`, I see very close timings for n_rows = 10000, cats = 5. If you try n_rows = 10000, cats = 50, I find that the setup cost for `convert_df` is ~1.5s (~600x worse than `convert_dict`). So you are right to go with `df.merge`, but only if the mapping is static / built once / not repeatedly read from csv.