# How to map values from a one column to another column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns `company_size` and `company_type`. `company_size` contains NaN values which I want to fill based on `company_type` column. How can I map to particular value so that I can fill the NaN values i.e missing values in `company_size` based on  `company_type`.

Example data:

```
 company_size    company_type
   10-50           startup
   1000+            PvtLtd
   NaN           Public Sector
   NaN              PvtLtd
   100-500       Public Sector
   NaN             startup
   100-500       Public Sector
```

Now based company_type I want to fill company_size.

```
startup -> 10-50
Public Sector -> 100-500
PvtLtd -> 1000+
```

Note both company_type and company_size are categorical variables.

Comment: I think there's a better dupe that actually does it from a dataframe not a dictionary

Comment: @xyzjayne Here I want to fill NaN values how can I do that in pandas ?

Comment: @stonerock you can select the rows where company_size is NaN

Comment: Perhaps this one? [remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is quite similar to your last question, which was answered. :))

Comment: I don't think it's mapping at all.  Why not just groupby `company_type` and ffill or bfill

Comment: @HarvIpan I don't think `between()` and `where()` will work

Comment: Instead of posting comments can someone please post answer which will be more helpful :)

Comment: Instead of asking questions that are already answered on the forum you could have done some research first and saved all of us some time :)

Comment: I think people are reluctant to post an answer because this question is almost certainly answered elsewhere on this site, and an almost identical question (asked by you) was answered earlier today, with a method that could easily be expanded to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort by company size to make sure that `NaN`s are at the end, then use `groupby` and `ffill`, then sort by index again to re-instate your original order:

```
df.sort_values('company_size').groupby('company_type').ffill().sort_index()

  company_size   company_type
0        10-50        startup
1        1000+         PvtLtd
2      100-500  Public Sector
3        1000+         PvtLtd
4      100-500  Public Sector
5        10-50        startup
6      100-500  Public Sector
```

Comment: I don't want to change the order of my data

Comment: Then just sort by index at then end (see my edited answer)

Answer (score 3):

**`groupby`** your company time, and **`transform('first')`** to get rid of NaN values:

```
df['company_size'] = df.groupby("company_type")["company_size"].transform("first")

  company_size  company_type
0        10-50       startup
1        1000+        PvtLtd
2      100-500  PublicSector
3        1000+        PvtLtd
4      100-500  PublicSector
5        10-50       startup
6      100-500  PublicSector
```