# Replace pandas column values using a key on another column and value from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, row

I have searched stackoverflow and gone over a few questions which are related to this, i.e

[Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

The key distinction is these questions answer how to replace column values with a key on the **same column** and a value from a dictionary.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['bacd', 'fdvdf', 'scsdc'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 4]})

df['key'].replace({'bacd' : 200, 'sdfvs': 5000}, inplace=True)

    key   value
0   200     1
1   fdvdf   2
2   scsdc   4
```

I am trying to use the **key** in a dictionary to identify the row, but **update a different column** (value in this case) instead of the key column.

Desired output:

```
    key     value
0   bacd    200
1   fdvdf   2
2   scsdc   4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`map`** with **`fillna`**

```
dct = {'bacd': 200, 'sdfvs': 5000}

df.assign(value=df.key.map(dct).fillna(df.value))

     key  value
0   bacd  200.0
1  fdvdf    2.0
2  scsdc    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a way to assign this inplace? Is this efficient?