# Panda Dataframe - Add values to new column based on criteria of other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add values to a new dataframe (df2) column (Discount%), the values in this column must be based on "Grid" and Entity from df1),
My structure is as following
[image]

so if for the same entity, the column in DF1 is 91-120 then it should add 20 to DF2 under Discount%, if the column in DF1 is 61-90 then it must add 5 to DF2 and so one.

The data is imported from a large csv file, so far I have tried below but if fill only with 0

```
for j in range(0,len(df1)):
for i in range(0,len(df2)):
if grid['91-120'][j] in df2['Grid'][i]:
#df['Grid%'][i] = grid['91-120'][j]
df2.loc[i, 'Grid%'] = df1['91-120'][j]
```

thank you

Comment: Can you please provide the code which can be used to reproduce the table and any of your tried approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently dealing with a similar problem related to iterating over a dataframe. You *really* don't want to do that if it could be avoided, especially if the dataframe contains duplicate values like your DF1.
I would recommend converting the reference dataframe, DF1, to a dictionary with the index orientation and then assigning the value to DF2 from that dictionary as shown below.

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Entity': ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4'], '0-60': [0, 0, 0, 0], '61-90': [0, 5, 10, 5], '91-120':[20, 5, 20, 20], '121-180':[10, 5, 12, 15], '181-240':[20, 5, 22, 25]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Entity': ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4'], 'Grid': ['360+', '61-90', '0-60', '91-120']})

print('DF2 before:')
print(DF2)

DF1.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
DF1.set_index('Entity', inplace=True)
d = DF1.to_dict('index')

def get_discount(entity, grid):
    if entity in d and grid in d[entity]:
        return d[entity][grid]
    else:
        return None

DF2['Discount %'] = DF2.apply(lambda x: get_discount(x['Entity'], x['Grid']), axis=1)

print('DF2 after:')
print(DF2)
```

I found this solution because, as I mentioned before, I'm currently working on a similar problem.
Knowing how detrimental iteration over a dataframe can be to the performance of a function, I realized it would be faster to assign a value from a dictionary. I looked up how to convert a dataframe to a dictionary on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary) and in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). Next, I looked up how to assign a value to a dataframe from a dictionary on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881503/assign-a-dictionary-value-to-a-dataframe-column-based-on-dictionary-key). I was trying the "dict" orientation at first. I could get it to assign all discount values for each "Entity" based on "Grid", but I couldn't select the one right discount value.
I couldn't find any other solutions online for assigning a value to a dataframe from a 2D dictionary, so I turned to ChatGPT. After ChatGPT did its thing, I was getting "None" in every field. Eventually, I got it to recommend changing the orientation of the dictionary from "dict" to "series". That also didn't work, but I figured I would try all the other orientations. Index worked.
The downside is that Discount % values are floats. The upside is it can handle cases where you don't have a value for Grid in the dictionary (e.g. where Grid is "360+").

Comment: Thank you really much Leon, that worked and i can adjust the fields accordingly. Frankly, i also tried all the possible solutions, with series, array, tulples and even dictionary but nothing worked for this 2d relation never thought about ChatGpt though,. I am not really worried about NaN values, those i can deal with... Appreciate and thank you for your efforts