# Apply a dictionary to text data

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
{0: 'group',
 1: 'still',
 2: 'earnings',
 3: 'shares',
 4: 'make',
 5: 'finally',
 6: 'amazon',
 7: 'deals',
 8: 'comes',
 9: 'york',
 10: 'iphones'}

print(df)

         0            1            2    ...     53      54         55
0      Group         still       shares  ...    deals  york     iphones
1      amazon        shares       make  ...    finally iphones earnings
...
```

The latter obtained from stripping an article with:

```
 df = df["text_articles"].str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

How can I translate every row of the dataframe using the dictionary, ultimately creating:

```
print(final_df)

         0            1            2    ...     53      54         55
0        0            1            3  ...       7       9          10
1        6            3            4  ...       5      10           2
...
```

Comment: what if some word is not contained in a dictionary?

Comment: Looks like you want to swap your dictionary keys/values around, and then just `.applymap` that to your DF?

Comment: I think you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict) :) All you have to do is swap you dictionary, as mentioned earlier, and than all the methods at the link can help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
        0       1       2       53       54       55
0   Group   still  shares    deals     york  iphones
1  amazon  shares    make  finally  iphones       aa
```

First swap keys with values to new dictionary:

```
d1 = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}
```

If non exist values is necessary replace to `NaN`s use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().map(d1))
print (df)
   0  1  2  53  54    55
0  0  1  3   7   9  10.0
1  6  3  4   5  10   NaN
```

Or if want replace non exist value to same scalar, e.g. `-1`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: d1.get(x.lower(), -1))
print (df)
   0  1  2  53  54  55
0  0  1  3   7   9  10
1  6  3  4   5  10  -1
```

And last if want no change:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).replace(d1)
print (df)
   0  1  2  53  54  55
0  0  1  3   7   9  10
1  6  3  4   5  10  aa
```

Comment: An amazing piece! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your request could be captured nicely with `df.replace`
But first you would have to turn your dictionary around.

```
d = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}
df = df.replace(d)
```