# How do I use mapping of dictionary for value correction?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series whose unique values are something like:

```
['toyota', 'toyouta', 'vokswagen', 'volkswagen,' 'vw', 'volvo']
```

Now I want to fix some of these values like:
toyouta -> toyota

(Note that not all values have mistakes such as volvo, toyota etc)

I've tried making a dictionary where key is the correct word and value is the word to be corrected and then map that onto my series.

This is how my code looks:

```
corrections = {'maxda': 'mazda', 'porcshce': 'porsche', 'toyota': 'toyouta', 'vokswagen': 'vw', 'volkswagen': 'vw'}
df.brands = df.brands.map(corrections)

print(df.brands.unique())
>>> [nan, 'mazda', 'porsche', 'toyouta', 'vw']
```

As you can see the problem is that this way, all values not present in the dictionary are automatically converted to `nan`. One solution is to map all the correct values to themselves, but I was hoping there could be a better way to go about this.

Comment: what about `df.brands.map(corrections).fillna(df.brands)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.brands = df.brands.map(corrections).fillna(df.brands)
```

Or:

```
df.brands = df.brands.map(lambda x: corrections.get(x, x))
```

Or:

```
df.brands = df.brands.replace(corrections)
```

Comment: Is this not a dupe...?

Comment: @cs95 - be free close if find it.

Comment: There's no point, it has already been answered. Although I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/4909087) (second answer) might help.

Comment: How did you quickly find the dupe questions? @cs95

Comment: While all of them work wonderfully, is there any reason to use one over the other? afaik all of them are vectorized functions?

Comment: @AakashDusane - I think `map` with dict and fillna should be vectorized, `replace` and `map` with `get` not. there are loops under the hood