# Pandas - Map values from dataframe if column entry exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df2` is shorter than `df1`. I am trying to copy an element `pred` from `df2` into `df1` if `pedestrian` in `df2` exists in `df1`. I have looked at many posts but can't find one that addresses my problem.

Using map returns me a `NaN` everywhere in `pred`.

```
d = df2.set_index('pedestrian')['pred'].to_dict()
df1['pred'] = df2['pred'].map(d)
```

The program doesn't stop running if I use replace.

```
d = df2.set_index('pedestrian')['pred'].to_dict()
df1.replace(d)
```

Below is `df1, df2` and what I would like the output to be.

df1

```
   pred   true            pedestrian     
0   -1     1    /data/jaad/image/0316/pedestrian/00...
1   -1     0    /data/jaad/image/0316/ped1/0001.png 
2   -1     0    /data/jaad/image/0316/ped2/0001.png
```

df2

```
      pred    true            pedestrian
0   0.628186    1   /data/jaad/image/0316/pedestrian/00...
1   0.171355    0   /data/jaad/image/0316/ped1/0001.png
2   0.628186    1   /data/jaad/image/0316/pedestrian/00...
```

output

```
   pred       true            pedestrian     
0   0.628186   1    /data/jaad/image/0316/pedestrian/00...
1   -1         0    /data/jaad/image/0316/ped1/0001.png 
2   -1         0    /data/jaad/image/0316/ped2/0001.png
```

Comment: You should be mapping `df1['pedestrian']`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/4333359) should have the solution you need: `df1['pred'] = df1['pedestrian'].map(d).fillna(df1.pred)`

Comment: @ALollz thank you very much ! silly mistake

Comment: You don't need to `to_dict()` at the of 'd'.  Map will handle a series.

Comment: And if you stick with the use of `replace`, you don't need `fillna()`.