# add a column based on the values of another column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

this is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['msft', 'amd', 'bac', 'citi'], 'close': [100, 30, 70, 80]})
```

I want to add another column called `sector` that checks the values of `symbol` and add the values that I want (`tech` for `amd` and `msft` for example).

My desired outcome looks like this:

```
   symbol  close   sector
  0  msft    100     tech
  1   amd     30     tech
  2   bac     70     bank
  3  citi     80     bank
```

Comment: do you have a heuristic defined for when it should add which `sector`?

Comment: So use `pandas.Series.map`. Where is your attempt?

Comment: Probably, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict, just assign it to a new column

Comment: @kawillzocken if symbol is equal to msft or amd sector is tech and for the other two I want it to be bank

Comment: @roganjosh can you post the answer please?

Comment: @Amir, yes that's obvious but what is the underlying logic? Questions and Answers on SO are better posed as generalizable solutions to a specific problem. In this case, do you have some grouping of symbols to different sectors (and how are these defined, in a list, stored in a dict, in another DataFrame)? Or do you need to assign a small subset of symbols to one thing and everything else to another? Solutions will vary depending upon this information.

Comment: @ALollz I want to assign each subset to a value.

Comment: No, why should I just post an answer to a question for which you have shown _no_ effort yourself? I already told you one potential method to use, did you actually look it up? You've already got feedback on some parts of the question that aren't clear, so even if I did post an answer, there's a chance that it doesn't solve your problem anyway

Comment: @Amir there are several ways to do what you want to achieve. Some of the possible ways of doing it include assign, numpy.where, dataframe.where, df[df["col"]]=="value" = 1 (assigning values based on condition) etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the sector-symbol relation is a straightforward lookup, you may use something like:

```py
symbol_sector = {
    'amd': 'tech',
    'msft': 'tech',
    'bac': 'bank',
    'citi': 'bank'
}

df['sector'] = df['symbol'].map(symbol_sector)
```

If your relation is 1 to N (one sector for many symbols) you can create the `symbol_sector` as follows:

```py
sector_symbol = { 
   'tech': {'msft', 'amd'}, 
   'bank': {'bac',  'city'}, 
}

symbol_sector = {
    symbol: sector
    for sector, symbols in sector_symbol.items()
    for symbol in symbols
}
```

Comment: You are right, I should've used Series.map, I'll update it

Answer (score 1):

heuristic:

```py
def assign_sector(sym): 
    if sym in ['msft', 'amd']: 
        return 'tech'
    return 'bank'
```

followed by:

```py
df['sector'] = df['symbol'].apply(assign_sector)
```

The `apply` function applies the function given in the argument, here `assign_sector`, to every value in the `pd.Series` `df['symbol']`. And this you can then insert into `df['sector']`, making a new column.

Comment: If it really is binary choice like this, then you should be using `np.where`, not `apply`. If it isn't a binary choice, neither approach works

Comment: My original data is not binary

Comment: @Amir how big is the dataset?

Comment: @Biarys about 160000 rows. With around 10 different  `sector`
 and  100 `symbol`s. I will try this answer later. I gotta go now