# How to translate in python using whole words as keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that contains tokens and their translations separated by an '=' (a line of it would be 'ACTION_PLAN=Action Plan'). I need to parse another file and substitute all the tokens for these values.

I managed to create a dict that has all tokens as keys and the phrases as values with the following code:

```
with open(dictionaryFileName) as d:
    commands = dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in d)
```

And it does what I intended, a dict with 'TOKEN:Phrase'

However, I now need to use this dict to substitute all the tokens in another file (a csv).

This file goes like 'ACTION_PLAN,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_MAP_REPORT,READ', every comma exactly one token, so I tried doing the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv(permissionFileName)

data["module_name"] = data["module_name"].str.translate(commands)

print(data)
```

where "module_name" is the name of the first column.

But it just returns exactly the same, no change at all and no exceptions either. I did some research and found that the dict needs to have unicode characters as keys, anyway to work around this other than creating the method myself?

Expected for this specific block of code:
input

```
module_name, group_name, perm_name
ACTION_PLAN,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_ACTION_PLAN_REPORT,READ
ACTION_PLAN,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_MAP_REPORT,READ
```

output:

```
Action Plan,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_ACTION_PLAN_REPORT,READ
Action Plan,GROUP_ANALYTICAL_MAP_REPORT,READ
```

dictionary:

```
ACTION_PLAN=Action Plan
```

Comment: have you tried `data["module_name"].replace(commands)`?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol it returns this exception TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'

Comment: ah sorry, updated command. Your always want to replace the entire value right? Or also parts of the string?

Comment: If you share both sample data and the desired output, it might be easier to understand the problem

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol yup, it'll always be the entire token for an entire expression

Comment: Then `Series.replace` should work, or have a look here for `map` options as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/1752959

Comment: @politicalscientist I've updated it with some more Data.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I'll be taking a look at this! Thank you.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol That works! Can you write an answer with this so I can upvote it??

Comment: `df['module_name'].map(commands)`?

Comment: @politicalscientist both actually worked but it seems map is faster so that's what I'm using. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/1752959) you can use either of the following, where `map` is said to be faster.
`data["module_name"].replace(commands)` or `data["module_name"].map(commands)`

If it would be partial replacements (for anyone else reading this) you can use `data["module_name"].replace(commands, regex=True)` which does 2 things, so use with caution:

- Enable partial replacement
- Allow regexes