# How to create a new column in pandas based on a conditional that references a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have stock data that I am trying to normalize but I am having an issue with creating a new column. I need to be able to add a value to the new column called Yahoo Ticker by referencing what is in the Ticker column and getting the corresponding value from the dictionary, using the Ticker value as the key. Here is a sample of the dictionary I am using:

```
dict = {'AAB': 'AAB.TO',
        'ABX': 'ABX.TO',
        'XDU': 'XDU-U.TO' }
```

I want to add a column to my dataframe with the value based off the dictionary key so for example I want to turn this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker':['AAB','ABX','XDU'] })
```

into a dataframe like this:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker':['AAB','ABX','AAV'],
                      'Yahoo Ticker':['AAB.TO','ABX.TO','XDU-U.TO']})
```

Previously I tried this but it didn't work

```
for index, value in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[df['Ticker'][index] in ticker_dictionary, 'Yahoo Tickers'] = ticker_dictionary[value]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAB', 'ABX', 'XDU']})

d = {'AAB': 'AAB.TO',
     'ABX': 'ABX.TO',
     'XDU': 'XDU-U.TO'}

df['Yahoo Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].map(d)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Ticker Yahoo Ticker
0    AAB       AAB.TO
1    ABX       ABX.TO
2    XDU     XDU-U.TO
```

Comment: @yatu, Thanks for pointing that, it seems that `d.get` works as well

Comment: yes, never tried though. But after all this has to be calling `dict.get`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for, a simple 1 line answer. Much appreciated!