# How to change name of few items in a column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame "df" with a column having enteries like NY, DM.....etc and many thousands of enteries , i am given a dictionary {'US' : 'United States', 'DM':'DENMARK'....etc} to replace all these short form names according to given dictionary, how to do that?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#Create a one-time dictionary with mapping of country against full name

d = {'US':'United States','DM':'DENMARK'}

#And use pandas map function to create a new column

df['Country_Full'] = df['Country'].map(d)

print(df)
  Country Country_Full
0      US   United States
1      DN   DENMARK
```

If you want to replace content from the existing column:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(d)
```

Comment: Also may be you can use [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) using which you can create a dictionary of countries abbreviations and names `import pycountry` ; 
`d = dict([(i.alpha_2,i.name) for i in pycountry.countries])` , gives `{'AW': 'Aruba',
 'AF': 'Afghanistan',
 'AO': 'Angola',
 ...}`

Comment: @anky - Something new to me, thanks for sharing!!