# Replace specific entries in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace all the '**male**' in the '**Sex**' column to **1** and all the '**female**' to **0**.

Here is my dataframe **df**:

```
    Pclass    Sex        Age    SibSp   Parch
0   3        male       22.0    1         0
1   1        female     38.0    1         0
2   3        female     26.0    0         0
3   1        female     35.0    1         0
4   3        male       35.0    0         0
5   3        male       2.0     3         1
6   3        female     27.0    0         2
7   2        female     14.0    1         0
8   3        female     4.0     1         1
9   1        female     58.0    0         0
```

I used the `pd.get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.Sex)
```

But it creates two columns male and female like this:

```
   female   male
0    0       1
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    0       1
```

On the Other hand I want only a single column of sex denoting **1 for male** and **0 for female**.

I know that i can use a for loop to iterate over all the rows and change but is there a pandorable way to do this??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```py
df["Sex"].replace({"male": 1, "female": 0}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare with `==` and then convert `boolean` type result to `int` type.

```
df['Sex_'] = (df.Sex == 'male').astype(int)
```

or If you want to use your current code `pd.get_dummies` you can just delete one column

```
df['Sex_'] = pd.get_dummies(df.Sex, drop_first = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `map` many labels, try:

```
dicts = {"male":1,"female":0}
df['Sex'].map(dicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there are only 'male' & 'female' values for 'Sex' column by 
`df['Sex'].value_counts()`
If that's the case then

```py
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].apply(lambda x:1 if x == 'male' else 0)
```