# How to join all Cities belonging to their state in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Actually, I have a dataframe that contains some states and I have a list of their few cities and I want to add those cities to that dataset and want to group each city with their state names. 
Eg.

```
#I have entered some random city names for example purpose 
city = ['Akola','Aurangabad','Dhule','Jalgaon','Mumbai','Mumbai Suburban','Nagpur']

       State    Cases   Active  Recovered   Death
0   Maharashtra 77793 2933  41402 1458  33681 1352  2710 123
1   Andhra Pradesh  4223 143    1613 67 2539 73 71 3
2   Karnataka   4320 257    2653 157    1610 96 57 4
3   Goa 166 87  109 87  57  0
4   Tamil Nadu  27256 1384  12134 786   14902 586   220 12
```

and I want those cities to add in a data frame in a new column like

```
       State    Cases   Active  Recovered   Death             |CITY    
0   Maharashtra 77793 2933  41402 1458  33681 1352  2710 123  |AKOLA
1   Maharashtra 77793 2933  41402 1458  33681 1352  2710 123  |DHULE
2   Maharashtra 77793 2933  41402 1458  33681 1352  2710 123  |MUMBAI
3   Andhra Pradesh  4223 143    1613 67 2539 73 71 3          |JALGAON
4   Andhra Pradesh  4223 143    1613 67 2539 73 71 3          |NAGPUR
5   Karnataka   4320 257    2653 157    1610 96 57 4
6   Goa 166 87  109 87  57  0
7   Tamil Nadu  27256 1384  12134 786   14902 586   220 12    |AURANGABAD
8   Tamil Nadu  27256 1384  12134 786   14902 586   220 12    |MUMBAI SUBURBAN
# data is wrong so please focus in format
```

Comment: Do you have a mapping of cities to states? If not, this seems more like a question for [gis stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or for a package/module that deals with geocoding. Pandas doesn't do this.

Comment: If the mapping is available, I think this post might be of use -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict

Comment: Actually I was doing web-scraping practice and these data I got from [extracting](https://www.ndtv.com/coronavirus/india-covid-19-tracker) so, I don't have any mapping

Comment: and also this question is not limited to `geospatial` instead of state there can be class1, class2......... etc and some may want to add student's name on their corresponding class so I am wondering how this can be solved