# How to replace value in whole dataframe based on dictionary when part of string match?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

Hi I have 2 dataframes where i have to use 1 dataframe to replace the value in other. I can normally create the dictionary to replace values in whole dataframe but I have a bit different value in other dataframe so i need condition where i can tell if the part of the string is matched then it should map the dictionary. 
The first dataframe is like this:

[image]

The second dataframe is like this:

```
        id        cars1                     cars2

        1     $ {hQOpelText.r1.val}        BMW
        2     $ {hQOpelText.r2.val}        $ {hQOpelText.r2.val}
        3     $ {hQOpelText.r3.val}        $ {hQOpelText.r5.val}
        4     $ {hQOpelText.r4.val}        Audi
        5     $ {hQOpelText.r5.val}        Audi
```

And i want resulted df like this:

```
        id        cars1                     cars2

        1     Opel Adam                   BMW
        2     Opel Astra Estate           Opel Astra Estate
        3     Opel Astra Hatchback        Opel Grandland x 
        4     Opel Astra Saloon           Audi
        5     Opel Grandland x            Audi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: No because i can't map directly the values as i have different values. If i create the dictionary then it will have different values as compared to second data-frame.

Comment: You can transform ``$ {hQOpelText.r1.val}`` to ``hQOpelTextr1`` if they are going to be consistent, then convert to dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is replace `.` to empty strings, then extract values by keys of dictionary, map and replace original if no match:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
func = lambda x: (x.str.replace('.', '', regex=False)
                  .str.extract(f'({"|".join(d.keys())})', expand=False)
                  .map(d)
                  .fillna(x))
df[c] = df[c].apply(func)

print (df)
   id                 cars1              cars2
0   1             Opel Adam                BMW
1   2     Opel Astra Estate  Opel Astra Estate
2   3  Opel Astra Hatchback    Opel Grandand X
3   4     Opel Astra Saloon               Audi
4   5       Opel Grandand X               Audi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer as always :) Can you differentiate between dataframes as you are using everywhere `df` so i am not sure where you are using what?

Comment: @s_khan92 - not sure if understand, but seems only way is necessary use `df1, df2, df3` instead `df` only if processing different `DataFrame`s and need distingush them.

Answer (score 1):

We can first change all the column values of type `$ {hQOpelText.r*.val}` in `df2` to adhere to the convention of the values used in `Variable` column in `df1` i.e `hQOpelTextr*`, then we can replace those values from the corresponding values from `df1`:

```
cols = df2.select_dtypes(object).columns
df2[cols] = df2[cols].transform(
    lambda s: (
        s.str.replace(r'\$\s*\{([^\.]+).*?([^\.]+).*?\}', r'\g<1>\g<2>')
        .replace(df1.set_index('Variable')['AUS'])
    )
)
```

---

```
# print(df2)
   id                 cars1              cars2
0   1              OpehAdam                BMW
1   2     Opel Astra Estate  Opel Astra Estate
2   3  Opel Astra Hatchback   Opel Grandland X
3   4     Opel Astra Saloon               Audi
4   5      Opel Grandland X               Audi
```