# Python Pandas - Replace NaN values using dict

Tags: python, pandas

With the following DF:

```
     A  B
0    a  1
1    b  2
2  NaN  1
3  NaN  2
```

I would like to replace NaN values of `A` based on the numeric representation of `B`, to get:

```
     A  B
0    a  1
1    b  2
2    a  1
3    b  2
```

I've built a dictionary of B/A values: `{1 : 'a', 2: 'b'}`

How can I apply the change to the NaN values?

Comment: nevemind, added to answer difference between using `map` and `replace` here, if in dict are all values like in `B` output is same (perfromnce the best test in real data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {1 : 'a', 2: 'b'}
df.A = df.A.fillna(df.B.map(d))
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  a  1
3  b  2
```

I suggest use `map` because `replace` is [slowier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874) and if no match in `map` is returned missing value (like original) not value of `B`:

```
df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(df["B"].replace({1 : 'a', 2: 'b'}))
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  a  1
3  3  3 <- changed last value to 3
```

---

```
d = {1 : 'a', 2: 'b'}
df.A = df.A.fillna(df.B.map(d))
print (df)
     A  B
0    a  1
1    b  2
2    a  1
3  NaN  3
```

Comment: `Series.map` is much faster than `.replace` and valid point that `map` doesn't replace values of `A` if there is no mapping. +1

Comment: @jezrael, can you please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090530/pandas-merge-two-dataframe-with-partial-match#65090910 ? thanks :)