# Replace multiple values with Dask mask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have this Dask `mask` code that sets 3 in a Dask data frame when the value of `incol` is 1:

```
ddf['outcol'] = ddf['incol'].mask(ddf['incol'] == 1, 3)
```

Now, I have to replace the values given 50 conditions such as:

```
if `incol` == 1 then set 3
if `incol` == 2 then set 8
: : :
: : :
```

Is it possible to do this in a single Dask statement (doesn't have to be `mask`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as these replacements do not depend on the values across different rows and hence can be applied in any order, it's possible to achieve this with `.map_partitions`:

```py
def apply_masks(df):
   # implement the mask logic here, for example
   df['outcol'] = df['incol'].mask(df['incol'] == 1, 3)
   return df

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(apply_masks)
```

Note that there is a potential problem with repeated application of `.mask()` since it will overwrite the previous results. So, depending on your use case, in the `apply_masks` function above the second application of the mask might need to either control for changed values in `outcol` or apply the mask to `outcol` column (with the caveat that masks will need to be applied in such an order that doesn't lead to a miscalculation, e.g. 1 is remapped into 3 and then then 3 remapped into 1).

If your application is such that you are writing to the same column `outcol`, then you probably want `.replace` or `.map` option (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/10693596) for a good explanation of the difference between these options).

So, in that case the workflow would be:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['incol'])

import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

replace_logic = {
    1: 3,
    2: 8,
    3: 2,
    # and so on ...
}

ddf['outcol'] = ddf['incol'].map(replace_logic).fillna(ddf['incol']).astype('int')

print(ddf.compute())
```

Comment: why are you using the `fillna` function?

Comment: if there is no `fillna` then the values not encoded in `replace_logic` will be `nan`. If you want to avoid that, then use `.replace` but it will be slower.