# Need help using pandas to read a column and print a new column in .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

I am trying to use pandas to read a column in an excel file and print a new column using my input. I am trying to convert 3-letter code to 1-letter code. So far, I've written this code, but when I run it, it will not print anything in the last column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\seqadv.csv') 
print (df)

codes = []
for i in df['WT_RESIDUE']:
   if i == 'ALA':
    codes.append('A')
   if i == 'ARG':
    codes.append('R')
   if i == 'ASN':
    codes.append('N')
   if i == 'ASP':
    codes.append('D')
   if i == 'CYS':
    codes.append('C')
   if i == 'GLU':
    codes.append('E')
    print (codes)
codes = df ['MUTATION_CODE']
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\seqadv3.csv')
```

[image: excel headers]

Comment: The assignment codes = df ['MUTATION_CODE'] should be reversed. It is better to use the apply method of the dataframe.

Comment: Still won't show anything in the last column. I don't know how to apply dataframe and read from an excel file

Comment: No loop: `m = {'ALA': 'A', 'ARG': 'R', 'ASN': 'N', 'ASP': 'D', 'CYS': 'C', 'GLU': 'E'}`, `df['MUTATION_CODE'] = df['WT_RESIDUE'].map(m).fillna('')`.

Comment: Console says: "SyntaxError: cannot assign to dict display" What does this mean?

Comment: I see you are using my sript :). I think you need to write: df['mulation_code'] = codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to define a dictionary with your replacement values, and then use either `map()` or `replace()` on your existing column to create your new column.  The difference between the two is that

- `replace()` will not change values not in the dictionary keys
- `map()` will replace any values not in the dictionary keys with the dictionary's default value (if it has one) or with NaN (if the dictionary doesn't have a default value)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WT_RESIDUE':['ALA', 'REMARK', 'VAL', 'CYS', 'GLU']})

codes = {'ALA':'A', 'ARG':'R', 'ASN':'N', 'ASP':'D', 'CYS':'C', 'GLU':'E'}

df['code_m'] = df['WT_RESIDUE'].map(codes)
df['code_r'] = df['WT_RESIDUE'].replace(codes)


In: df
Out: 
  WT_RESIDUE code_m  code_r
0        ALA      A       A
1     REMARK    NaN  REMARK
2        VAL    NaN     VAL
3        CYS      C       C
4        GLU      E       E
```

More detailed information is here: [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't replace MUTATION_CODE when I run the code. The column remains empty

Comment: Hi, I removed the line ```df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WT_RESIDUE':['ALA', 'REMARK', 'VAL', 'CYS', 'GLU']})``` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
df['MUTATION_CODE'] = codes
```

Comment: 1) Looping is inefficient, and 2) this won't work if there's a value in `WT_RESIDUE` that is not handled by the if logic.

Comment: I made sure to include all values for WT_Residue.