# Alternative options to replace column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3], "2000": ['p', 'w', nan], "2001": ['p', 'p', nan], "2002": ['p', nan, 'p']})
```

```
id  2000 2001 2002
1    p    p     p
2    w    p     nan
3    nan  nan   p
```

I want to replace all the 'p' and 'w' by '1'.

I applied :

```
df['2000'] = df['2000'].str.replace('p','1')
df['2000'] = df['2000'].str.replace('w','1')

df['2001'] = df['2001'].str.replace('p','1')
df['2001'] = df['2001'].str.replace('w','1')
```

and so on for each year and it is working.

```
id  2000 2001 2002
1    1    1     1
2    1    1     nan
3    nan  nan   1
```

Since, I have a very long data, I am wondering whether there any alternative command, that I can use for the entire data-frame, instead of coding for each column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: `df.set_index('id').replace('p', '1').reset_index()`?

Comment: @gold_cy it gives me the same long procedure.

Comment: creating a dictionary to remap values is a long procedure? what if different letters need different values...

Comment: @gold-cy,  I already said that I have a large number of column for like 50 years and I know how to do it separately for each column, the link that u have provided me , it also requires to replace for each column. I hope you understand and I appreciate your response.

Comment: you're missing the point, best of luck since it seems you did not _properly_ read that link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> df.replace({r'[pw]': 1}, regex=True)
   id  2000  2001  2002
0   1   1.0   1.0   1.0
1   2   1.0   1.0   NaN
2   3   NaN   NaN   1.0
```