# Alternative to np.where when requiring numerous changes to a column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In Python, if I have a data frame in which I want to alter the contents in a particular column from one specific value to another, I so far use the following method using numpy:

```
df["Country"] = np.where(df["Country"] == "UK", "United Kingdom", df["Country"])
df["Country"] = np.where(df["Country"] == "USA", "United States", df["Country"])
```

I have about 100 of these types of changes, which looks ungainly in code. Can an example be provided in how to alter the above code in a way that would look more elegant when having numerous extra changes?

Comment: You could replace with a `dict` ->  `df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace({'UK': 'United Kingdom', 'USA': 'United States'})`

Comment: See [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20250771/15497888)

Comment: how about a merge / join to another dataframe that soft encodes your mappings?