# Converting numeric labels back to original strings

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, categorical-data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data = pd.read_csv('data/TrainingData_unsubscribe.csv')

data['labels'] = data['Category'].factorize()[0]

#vectorize the features
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', stop_words='english')


x_vectors = tfidf.fit_transform(data.msgContent)
#split the data
x = x_vectors
y = data.labels
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

x_train = x_train.toarray()
x_train.shape
x.shape
x_test = x_test.toarray()
preds = x_vectors.toarray()
#Random seed and callback
stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=10)
#create the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(pd.unique(y)), activation='softmax')
    ])

#compile the model
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#fit the model
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=500, verbose=0, callbacks=[stop])

#elavuation
print('\nEvaluation: ')
model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)

predictions = model.predict(preds)
len(pd.unique(y))

data["Prediction"] = predictions.argmax(axis=1)
output = data.drop(["labels"], axis=1)
category_ids = data[["Category", "labels"]].drop_duplicates()
output['Prediction'] =
```

Originally converted string labels to numeric ones using factorize():

```
data['labels'] = data['Category'].factorize()[0]
```

Now I'm trying to convert the labels back to their initial string variables. I've created a DF with the mapped values

| Category | labels |
| --- | --- |
| HardBounce | 0 |
| SoftBounce | 1 |

etc...

is it possible to map a df column using another df as a reference for the map?
I've been unable to find any docs that show how to do this.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your specific question, in general one thing that can be helpful is to do all of your transformations inside the sklearn framework. For example, using [labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) instead of `factorize()` would give you access to the `inverse_transform` method to do exactly what you're after

Comment: Rather than storing your mappings in a dataframe, why not use a dictionary and then the solution in [Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict) would work. Note, You can alos just use `df.to_dict()` to get your current mappings into dictionary format