# Generate new column based on values of another column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that outputs a Product Code:

| Product Code | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 61725 | $50 |
| 26753 | $12 |
| 61725 | $30 |
| 176534 | $10 |

How do I create a new column called "Product Name" that outputs the correct Product Name based on Product code? I have a dictionary that looks like this:

Product_Mapping = {61725:'Apples', 26753:'Cherries',176534:'Peaches'}

I want my final df to look like this:

| Product Code | Price | Product Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 61725 | $50 | Apples |
| 26753 | $12 | Cherries |
| 61725 | $30 | Apples |
| 176534 | $10 | Peaches |

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide some starter code

Comment: related -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```
Product_Mapping = {61725:'Apples', 26753:'Cherries',176534:'Peaches'}

df["Product Name"] = df["Product Code"].map(Product_Mapping)


print(df)

   Product Code Price Product Name
0         61725   $50       Apples
1         26753   $12     Cherries
2         61725   $30       Apples
3        176534   $10      Peaches
```