# How can I remap values in a pandas column using a random draw from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, random

#### Context

I have a dataframe where I need to remap a column to different values. For some values the mapping is ambiguous, the resulting value should be chosen randomly from a list everytime the value to be mapped is encountered.

For example, the values in the columns should be remapped in the following way:

- 1 ➝ 'a'
- 2 ➝ 'b' or 'c', chosen at random
- 3 ➝ 'd'

If there are two rows with a `2`, a random draw should be done each time to determine if the value should be mapped to `b` or to `c`.

#### Example data

Here is some example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], "col2": [2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1]})
```

#### What I've looked into

I've tried using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and a [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) call with a mapping dictionary (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/1256347)):

```py
choice_list = ["b", "c"]
map_dict = {1: "a", 2: random.choice(choice_list), 3: "d"}
df["remap"] = df.col2.map(map_dict)
```

I found that in the remapping of value `2`, always a single value was chosen from the `choice_list` for all rows, e.g. all `b`'s:

```
   col1  col2 remap
0     1     2     b
1     2     2     b
2     3     2     b
3     4     3     d
4     5     1     a
5     6     2     b
6     7     2     b
7     8     1     a
```

Something similar happens when I use the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method.

My expected outcome would be something like:

```
   col1  col2 remap
0     1     2     b
1     2     2     c
2     3     2     b
3     4     3     d
4     5     1     a
5     6     2     b
6     7     2     c
7     8     1     a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### what is wrong

By doing the following, you select once and for all the replacement value, which you don't want.

```
map_dict = {1: "a", 2: random.choice(choice_list), 3: "d"}
```

##### how to fix it

You need to make your random choice every time your map.

For this change the `map_dict` format and use a small wrapper:

```
import random
map_dict = {1: ["a"], 2: ["b", "c"], 3: ["d"]}
df["remap"] = df.col2.map(lambda x: random.choice(map_dict[x]))
```

possible output:

```
   col1  col2 remap
0     1     2     c
1     2     2     b
2     3     2     c
3     4     3     d
4     5     1     a
5     6     2     b
6     7     2     c
7     8     1     a
```

##### faster alternative for large datasets

If you have many rows (tens of thousands), this alternative will be faster:

```
map_dict = {1: ["a"], 2: ["b", "c"], 3: ["d"]}
map_s = pd.Series(map_dict, name='remap').explode()

(df.merge(map_s, left_on='col2', right_index=True)
   .groupby(level=0).sample(1)
)
```