# Replace all specific values in dataframe with value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to replace all values of 999999 with another column value, while leaving all other values alone. Here is an example of what I have now:

| Account | max val | Biology | Statistics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 100 | 999999 | 200 |
| Frank | 150 | 150 | 999999 |
| Wendy | 90 | 999999 | 100 |

Here is what I want the dataframe to look like:

| Account | max val | Biology | Statistics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 100 | 100 | 200 |
| Frank | 150 | 150 | 150 |
| Wendy | 90 | 90 | 100 |

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably all your columns are numeric, not string, or mixed string and numeric. (Because if they were string, you could use `df.map()`; see [Remap values in pandas column with a dict, preserve NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict-preserve-nans))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do

```
df = df.mask(df==999999).ffill(axis = 1)
  Account max val Biology Statistics
0    Bill     100     100      200.0
1   Frank     150   150.0      150.0
2   Wendy      90      90      100.0
```