# TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, file-io, typeerror

I want to create `imgs` variable to load all the images in "./input/hubmap-organ-segmentation/train_images/" folder. My code raised `TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'` error.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import cv2

BASE_PATH = "./input/hubmap-organ-segmentation/"
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "train.csv"))
    
all_image_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "train_images", "**", "*.tiff"), recursive=True)
train_img_map = {int(x[:-5].rsplit("/", 1)[-1]):x for x in all_image_files}
df.insert(3, "img_path", image_ids.map(train_img_map))

imgs = [cv2.imread(img_path)[..., ::-1] for img_path in df.img_path.values]
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [132], in <cell line: 38>()
     37 ftu_crop_map = {}
     38 for _organ in ORGANS:
     39     #sub_df = df[df.organ==_organ].sample(N_EX)
---> 40     imgs = [cv2.imread(img_path)[..., ::-1] for img_path in df.img_path.values]

Input In [132], in <listcomp>(.0)
     37 ftu_crop_map = {}
     38 for _organ in ORGANS:
     39     #sub_df = df[df.organ==_organ].sample(N_EX)
---> 40     imgs = [cv2.imread(img_path)[..., ::-1] for img_path in df.img_path.values]

TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
```

Example of `img_path`:

```py
df.img_path[0]
'./input/hubmap-organ-segmentation/train_images/10044.tiff'
```

Comment: Printing `df.img_path[0]` doesn't tell you anything about what `df.img_path.values` returns.  pandas does a HUGE number of automatic type conversions that hide what's really going on.  Do you really need to pass these into a dataframe, as opposed to keeping it as a list, where you KNOW what's going on?

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to pass these into a dataframe.

Comment: Why?  You certainly don't need it as a dataframe for THIS work.  Just keep it as a list now, and convert it later if you need to write an Excel file or something.

Comment: @TimRoberts How do I keep it as a list? `imgs = [cv2.imread(img_path.split(" "))[..., ::-1] for img_path in df.img_path.values]` returned the same error.

Comment: I've also tried `imgs = [cv2.imread(img_path.split( " " ))[..., ::-1] for img_path in df.dropna().img_path.values]`

Comment: I mean start from `train_image_map`, BEFORE you convert to a dataframe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error, make sure the value passed to `cv2.imread()` is a string (which is a filepath). For example, passing a list raises this error:

```py
cv2.imread(['img1.png', 'img2.png'])  # <--- TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
```

In this case, since each file need to be read one by one, to solve this particular issue, use a list comprehension:

```py
imgs = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ['img1.png', 'img2.png']]  # <--- OK
```

---

In the case in the OP, NaN was passed to it, which caused the error.

```py
cv2.imread(float('nan'))  # <--- TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
```

This is because the list comprehension where `imread()` is called is a loop over a dataframe column which is created using the `Series.map()` method. When the keys do not exist in the mapping, it returns a NaN (see for example [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20250771/19123103)), so it is very likely that there were some NaN values in the dataframe column that contains the image filepaths.

An example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'img_path': ['img1.png', np.nan]})      # <--- has non-string value
[cv2.imread(img_path) for img_path in df['img_path']]      # <--- TypeError:


df = pd.DataFrame({'img_path': ['img1.png', 'img2.png']})  # <--- all strings
[cv2.imread(img_path) for img_path in df['img_path']]      # <--- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this snipped to read image instead of cv2.imread()

```
_,croped_image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image_path)
nprr = np.frombuffer(croped_image_bytes,np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(nprr,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```