# Replace and aggregate rows in pandas according to condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
   lft rel rgt num
0   t3  r3  z2  3
1   t1  r3  x1  9
2   x2  r3  t2  8
3   x4  r1  t2  4
4   t1  r1  z3  1
5   x1  r1  t2  2
6   x2  r2  t4  4
7   z3  r2  t4  5
8   t4  r3  x3  4
9   z1  r2  t3  4
```

And a reference dictionary:

```
replacement_dict = {
    'X1' : ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
    'Y1' : ['y1', 'y2'],
    'Z1' : ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']
}
```

My goal is to replace all occurrences of `replacement_dict['X1']` with 'X1', and then compute the group-wise sum of `num` rows.

For example, any instance of 'x1', 'x2', 'x3' or 'x4' will be replaced by 'X1', etc., and the total of the 'X1'-'r1'-'t2' group (which is created by the remapping above) is 6, etc.

So my desired output is:

```
    lft rel rgt num
0   X1  r3  t2  8
1   X1  r1  t2  6
2   X1  r2  t4  4
3   t1  r3  X1  9
4   t4  r3  X1  4
```

I am working with a dataframe with 6 million rows and a replacement dictionary with 60,000 keys. This is taking forever using a simple row wise extraction and replacement.

How can this (specifically the last part) be scaled efficiently? Is there a pandas trick that someone can recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reverse the `replacement_dict` mapping and `map()` this new mapping to each of lft and rgt columns to substitute certain values (e.g. x1->X1, y2->Y1 etc.). As some values in lft and rgt columns don't exist in the mapping (e.g. t1, t2 etc.), call `fillna()` to fill in these values.<sup>1</sup>

You may also `stack()` the columns whose values need to be replaced (lft and rgt), call map+fillna and `unstack()` back but because there are only 2 columns, it may not be worth the trouble for this particular case.

The second part of the question may be answered by summing num values after grouping by lft, rel and rgt columns; so `groupby().sum()` should do the trick.

```py
# reverse replacement map
reverse_map = {v : k for k, li in replacement_dict.items() for v in li}

# substitute values in lft column using reverse_map
df['lft'] = df['lft'].map(reverse_map).fillna(df['lft'])
# substitute values in rgt column using reverse_map
df['rgt'] = df['rgt'].map(reverse_map).fillna(df['rgt'])

# sum values in num column by groups
result = df.groupby(['lft', 'rel', 'rgt'], as_index=False)['num'].sum()
```

<sup>1</sup>: `map()` + `fillna()` may perform better for your use case than `replace()` because under the hood, `map()` implements a Cython optimized `take_nd()` method that performs particularly well if there are a lot of values to replace, while `replace()` implements `replace_list()` method which uses a Python loop. So if `replacement_dict` is particularly large (which it is in your case), the difference in performance will be huge, but if `replacement_dict` is small, `replace()` may outperform `map()`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933438/19123103), which includes different benchmarks showing interaction between dictionary size and dataframe length, to get an idea of when to use `replace` and when to use `map`+`fillna`.

Answer (score 6):

If you flip the keys and values of your `replacement_dict`, things become a lot easier:

```py
new_replacement_dict = {
    v: key
    for key, values in replacement_dict.items()
    for v in values
}

cols = ["lft", "rel", "rgt"]
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(new_replacement_dict)
df.groupby(cols).sum()
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I commented the steps

```
#reverse dict to dissolve the lists as values
reversed_dict = {v:k for k,val in replacement_dict.items() for v in val}

# replace the values
cols = ['lft', 'rel', 'rgt']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(reversed_dict)

# filter rows where X1 is anywhere in the columns
df = df[df.eq('X1').any(axis=1)]

# sum the duplicate rows
out = df_filtered.groupby(cols).sum().reset_index()
print(out)
```

Output:

```
  lft rel rgt  num
0  X1  r1  t2    6
1  X1  r2  t4    4
2  X1  r3  t2    8
3  t1  r3  X1    9
4  t4  r3  X1    4
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas has built in function *replace* that is faster than going through the whole dataframe with .loc

You can also pass a list in it making our dictionary good fit for it

```
keys = replacement_dict.keys()

# Loop through every value in our dictionary and get the replacements

for key in keys:
  DF = DF.replace(to_replace=replacement_dict[key], value=key)
```

Comment: How do I sum the 'num' field for similar rows once I have done the replacement?

Comment: I didn't quite understand where do we get the two rows to sum up to the num column. Could you specify that?

Comment: Once the replacement is implemented, there will be rows that the same ['lft','rel','rgt'] values but different 'num' values (rows 3 and 5 above). These are the same rows with different 'weights'. I'd like to combine them

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df[['lft','rgt']] = ( df[['lft','rgt']]
    .replace({it:k for k, v in replacement_dict.items() for it in v}) )
df = ( df[(df.lft == 'X1') | (df.rgt == 'X1')]
    .groupby(['lft','rel','rgt']).sum().reset_index() )
```

Output:

```
  lft rel rgt  num
0  X1  r1  t2    6
1  X1  r2  t4    4
2  X1  r3  t2    8
3  t1  r3  X1    9
4  t4  r3  X1    4
```

Explanation:

- `replace()` uses a reversed version of the dictionary to replace items from lists in the original dict with the corresponding keys in the relevant df columns `lft` and `rgt`
- after filtering for rows with `'X1'` found in either `lft` or `rgt`, use `groupby()`, `sum()` and `reset_index()` to sum the `num` column for unique `lft, rel, rgt` group keys and restore the group components from index levels to columns.

---

As an alternative, we can use `query()` to select only rows containing `'X1'`:

```py
df[['lft','rgt']] = ( df[['lft','rgt']]
    .replace({it:k for k, v in replacement_dict.items() for it in v}) )
df = ( df.query("lft=='X1' or rgt=='X1'")
    .groupby(['lft','rel','rgt']).sum().reset_index() )
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of great answers. I avoid the need for the dict and use a `df.apply()` like this to generate new data.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd


# # create the data
x = '''
lft rel rgt num
t3 r3 z2 3
t1 r3 x1 9
x2 r3 t2 8
x4 r1 t2 4
t1 r1 z3 1
x1 r1 t2 2
x2 r2 t4 4
z3 r2 t4 5
t4 r3 x3 4
z1 r2 t3 4
'''


data = io.StringIO(x)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=' ')
print(df)

replacement_dict = {
    'X1' : ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
    'Y1' : ['y1', 'y2'],
    'Z1' : ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']
}


def replace(x):
    # which key to check
    key_check = x[0] + '1'
    key_check = key_check.upper()

    return key_check


df['new'] = df['lft'].apply(replace)
df
```

return this:

```
  lft rel rgt  num
0  t3  r3  z2    3
1  t1  r3  x1    9
2  x2  r3  t2    8
3  x4  r1  t2    4
4  t1  r1  z3    1
5  x1  r1  t2    2
6  x2  r2  t4    4
7  z3  r2  t4    5
8  t4  r3  x3    4
9  z1  r2  t3    4
  lft rel rgt  num new
0  t3  r3  z2    3  T1
1  t1  r3  x1    9  T1
2  x2  r3  t2    8  X1
3  x4  r1  t2    4  X1
4  t1  r1  z3    1  T1
5  x1  r1  t2    2  X1
6  x2  r2  t4    4  X1
7  z3  r2  t4    5  Z1
8  t4  r3  x3    4  T1
9  z1  r2  t3    4  Z1
```