# create new column from dictionary key if condition matches in values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a dictionary

```
df
col1 col2
a      a1
b      b1
c      c1
d      d1
```

```
dict
company = {
    'abcd': [a1],
    'efgh': [b1],
    'rewr': [c1],
    'fsdf': [d1]
}
```

I need to create new column from dictionary key if the value matches the column in df so that my output df is:

```
col1 col2  new_col
a      a1   abcd
b      b1   efgh
c      c1   rewr
d      d1   fsdf
```

my current loop for that is below but is there a more pythonic way of doing this:

```
def find_value(v):
    found = False
    for k in dic.keys():
        if v in dic[k]: 
            return k
    if not found: return None

df['new_col'] = dataset['col2'].apply(find_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on reversed dictionary.

```
df['new_col'] = df['col2'].map({v[0]:k for k,v in company.items()})
```

Comment: Missing matches will result in `np.nan` though, not `None`

Comment: You can always replace np.nan with None but I don't recommend it replacing with None.

Answer (score 0):

```python
df['new_col'] = df['col2']
df.replace({"new_col": {v[0]: k for k, v in company.items()}})
```

###### Output:

```
    col1    col2    new_col
0   a       a1      abcd
1   b       b1      efgh
2   c       c1      rewr
3   d       d1      fsdf
```

Or a oneliner:

```python
df['new_col'] = df.col2.replace({v[0]: k for k, v in company.items()})
```

[Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping)
[Remap values in pandas column with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict-preserve-nans)

For the values that did not match, they will be addeed with the same values as `col2`, hence can be nullified with:

```python
df['new_col'][df.new_col == df.col2] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to streamline `find_value` (I'm inclined to call it `find_key` since that is what you return) here is a snippet that leverages the `items` method from dictionary.  Note, `found` is not needed since it will always return the key if `target_value` is found otherwise it will return `None`.  Strictly speaking, the `return None` line is not needed since Python functions return `None` by default, but it makes the code more clear in this case to be explicit.

```
def find_key(target_value):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if v == target_value:
            return k
    return None
```